# Can I update the TypeScript version in WebStorm?

Tags: typescript, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I'm currently using WebStorm 10.0.4. And the latest TypeScript version is 1.5.3. But in WebStorm there are an older version of TypeScript. How can I update my TypeScript version in WebStorm?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the default settings dialog go to...

- Languages & Frameworks
- TypeScript
- Check "Enable TypeScript Compiler"
- Click "Edit" button
- Select "Custom directory"
- Select your install directory
- "OK" all prompts
- Enjoy TypeScript 1.5.3