# Angular HTTP GET with TypeScript error http.get(...).map is not a function in [null]

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I have a problem with HTTP in Angular.

I just want to `GET` a `JSON` list and show it in the view.

### Service class

```
import {Injectable} from "angular2/core";
import {Hall} from "./hall";
import {Http} from "angular2/http";
@Injectable()
export class HallService {
    public http:Http;
    public static PATH:string = 'app/backend/'    

    constructor(http:Http) {
        this.http=http;
    }

    getHalls() {
           return this.http.get(HallService.PATH + 'hall.json').map((res:Response) => res.json());
    }
}
```

And in the `HallListComponent` I call the `getHalls` method from the service:

```
export class HallListComponent implements OnInit {
    public halls:Hall[];
    public _selectedId:number;

    constructor(private _router:Router,
                private _routeParams:RouteParams,
                private _service:HallService) {
        this._selectedId = +_routeParams.get('id');
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this._service.getHalls().subscribe((halls:Hall[])=>{ 
            this.halls=halls;
        });
    }
}
```

However, I got an exception:

> TypeError: this.http.get(...).map is not a function in [null]

### hall-center.component

```
import {Component} from "angular2/core";
import {RouterOutlet} from "angular2/router";
import {HallService} from "./hall.service";
import {RouteConfig} from "angular2/router";
import {HallListComponent} from "./hall-list.component";
import {HallDetailComponent} from "./hall-detail.component";
@Component({
    template:`
        <h2>my app</h2>
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    `,
    directives: [RouterOutlet],
    providers: [HallService]
})

@RouteConfig([
    {path: '/',         name: 'HallCenter', component:HallListComponent, useAsDefault:true},
    {path: '/hall-list', name: 'HallList', component:HallListComponent}
])

export class HallCenterComponent{}
```

### app.component

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {ROUTER_DIRECTIVES} from "angular2/router";
import {RouteConfig} from "angular2/router";
import {HallCenterComponent} from "./hall/hall-center.component";
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
        <h1>Examenopdracht Factory</h1>
        <a [routerLink]="['HallCenter']">Hall overview</a>
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    `,
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})

@RouteConfig([
    {path: '/hall-center/...', name:'HallCenter',component:HallCenterComponent,useAsDefault:true}
])
export class AppComponent { }
```

### tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES5",
    "module": "system",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Doesn't http.get return a promise?

Comment: @bmm6o The new `Http` service returns an observable

Comment: I ran into a nearly identical issue, trying to migrate a project from Angular2 beta-17 to final release.  The issue for me was my IDE though, using VS 2015, Update 3.  The TypeScript language service extension was still at `1.8.36`, whereas as the ng2 quickstart guide (as I write this) is using `"typescript": "^2.0.2"`.  Upgrading the TS lang. service via Extensions and Updates did the trick for me.  While that update was being installed I came across [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37079769), which ends with the same conclusion.

Comment: For phpstorm/webstorm, updating the typescript version with the library of my project also solved the problem. I followed the steps of this SO answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31608934/1291428

Answer (score 541, accepted):

I think that you need to import this:

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'
```

Or more generally this if you want to have more methods for observables.
**WARNING: This will import all 50+ operators and add them to your application, thus affecting your bundle size and load times.**

```
import 'rxjs/Rx';
```

See [this issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/5632#issuecomment-167026172) for more details.

Comment: Which errors still remain? You can ask some specific questions regarding this on stackoverflow ;-) This question could perhaps help you as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34450131/how-to-consume-http-component-efficiently-in-angular-2-beta/34450948#34450948.

Comment: As of Angular 2 RC 0, this is no longer required.

Comment: @OnurYıldırım, using rc.4, this import is still required, unless I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: Please don't use 'import 'rxjs/Rx';' because it imports everything and rxjs tends to be pretty big. Import operators one by one as you need them.

Comment: Angular 2 with rxjs: 5.0.0-beta.12 here.
And I still had to `import 'rxjs/add/operator/do'`... While we don't have to do this for `.map()` anymore. But this helped my `.do()` case, to realize I specifically need to import it. Thank you! One up vote from me :)

Comment: ah this is right! I was importing { Observable } from rxjs/Rx but that's not enough. you still need to add that import of .../map

Comment: The import can go into your app.module.ts to be used across the application. Otherwise, import the pieces you need into your child modules. With tree-shaking, the impact of importing all is mitigated .

Comment: @Drag0 Will the angular CLI take care of this when compiling with `--prod`?

Comment: The rxjs/Rx import is often blacklisted, so it won't lint. Create a new project with the Angular CLI and you'll see.

Answer (score 84):

Just some background... The newly minted [Server Communication](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html) dev guide (finally) discusses/mentions/explains this:

> The RxJS library is quite large. Size matters when we build a production application and deploy it to mobile devices. We should include only those features that we actually need.
>
> Accordingly, Angular exposes a stripped down version of `Observable` in the `rxjs/Observable` module, a version that lacks almost all operators including the ones we'd like to use here such as the `map` method.
>
> It's up to us to add the operators we need. We could add each operator, one-by-one, until we had a custom Observable implementation tuned precisely to our requirements.

So as @Thierry already answered, we can just pull in the operators we need:

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/operator/delay';
import 'rxjs/operator/mergeMap';
import 'rxjs/operator/switchMap';
```

Or, if we're lazy we can pull in the full set of operators. **WARNING: this will add all 50+ operators to your app bundle, and will effect load times**

```
import 'rxjs/Rx';
```

Comment: import 'rxjs/Rx'; wow. and all my hair pulling instantly goes away. i can't believe this isn't printed all over the world for Rxjs/Angular2. thanks!!!

Comment: But it frequently won't lint, by default it's a blacklisted import. Create a new angular CLI project, you'll see. I love the convenience myself but the convention in the places I work in NYC is not to do it.

Answer (score 24):

From *rxjs 5.5* onwards, you can use the *pipeable* operators

```
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

**What is wrong with the** `import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';`

When we use this approach `map` operator will be patched to `observable.prototype`  and becomes a part of this object.

If later on, you decide to remove `map` operator from the code that handles the observable stream but fail to remove the corresponding import statement, the code that implements `map` remains a part of the `Observable.prototype`.

When the bundlers tries to eliminate the unused code (*a.k.a.* `tree shaking`), they may decide to keep the code of the  `map` operator in the Observable even though it’s not being used in the application.

**Solution** - `Pipeable operators`

*Pipeable* operators are pure functions and do not patch the *Observable*. You can import operators using the ES6 import syntax `import { map } from "rxjs/operators"` and then wrap them into a function `pipe()` that takes a variable number of parameters, i.e. chainable operators.

Something like this:

```
getHalls() {
    return this.http.get(HallService.PATH + 'hall.json')
    .pipe(
        map((res: Response) => res.json())
    );
}
```

Comment: Yeah, now currently with Rxjs version 7+, it's recommended to use pipeable operators by using pipe, nice one, I found all the previous answers old and not updated with the current versions of Angular and Rxjs

Answer (score 17):

With Angular 5 the RxJS import is improved.

Instead of

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
```

We can now

```
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

Comment: Using this approach,now in your build it will only include used operators ( map in this case), earlier it was including all the operators from rxjs library. check below link for more detail.

https://loiane.com/2017/08/angular-rxjs-imports/

Answer (score 15):

Using `Observable.subscribe` directly should work.

```
@Injectable()
export class HallService {
    public http:Http;
    public static PATH:string = 'app/backend/'    

    constructor(http:Http) {
        this.http=http;
    }

    getHalls() {
    // ########### No map
           return this.http.get(HallService.PATH + 'hall.json');
    }
}


export class HallListComponent implements OnInit {
    public halls:Hall[];
    / *** /
    ngOnInit() {
        this._service.getHalls()
           .subscribe(halls => this.halls = halls.json()); // <<--
    }
}
```

Comment: This isn't a very efficient approach. For instance if there are multiple subscribers they will each have to run map on the data, rather than just doing it once in the service. I think OP had the right approach, just didn't have the right module loaded to use it.

Answer (score 5):

For Angular versions 5 and above, the updated importing line looks like :

```
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

OR

```
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

Also these versions totally supports Pipable Operators so you can easily use .pipe() and .subscribe().

If you are using Angular version 2, then the following line should work absolutely fine :

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
```

OR

```
import 'rxjs/add/operators/map';
```

If you still encounter a problem then you must go with :

```
import 'rxjs/Rx';
```

I won't prefer you to use it directly bcoz it boosts the Load time, as it has a large number of operators in it (useful and un-useful ones) which is not a good practice according to the industry norms, so make sure you try using the above mentioned importing lines first, and if that not works then you should go for rxjs/Rx

Answer (score 4):

The **map** you using here is not the `.map()` in JavaScript, it's Rxjs map function which working on `Observables` in Angular.

So in that case you need to import it if you'd like to use map on the result data.

> `map(project: function(value: T, index: number): R, thisArg: any): Observable<R>` Applies a given project function to each value emitted
> by the source Observable, and emits the resulting values as an
> Observable.

So simply import it like this:

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
```

Answer (score 4):

I have a solution of this problem

Install this package:

```
npm install rxjs@6 rxjs-compat@6 --save
```

then import this library

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'
```

finally restart your ionic project then

```
ionic serve -l
```

Answer (score 3):

Angular version 6 "0.6.8" 
rxjs version 6 "^6.0.0"

this solution is  for :

```
  "@angular-devkit/core": "0.6.8",
  "rxjs": "^6.0.0"
```

as we all know angular is being developed every day so there are lots of changes every day and this solution is for angular 6 and rxjs 6
first to work with http yo should import it from : 
 after all you have to declare the HttpModule in app.module.ts

```
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
```

and you have to add HttpModule to Ngmodule -> **imports**

```
  imports: [
    HttpModule,
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)
  ],
```

second  to work with map you should first import pipe :

```
import { pipe } from 'rxjs';
```

third you need the map function  import from :

```
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

you have to use map inside pipe like this exemple :

```
 constructor(public http:Http){  }

    getusersGET(){
        return this.http.get('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users').pipe(
         map(res => res.json()  )  );
    }
```

that works perfectly good luck !

Answer (score 2):

Since **Http** service in **angular2** returns an **Observable** type,
From your Angular2 installation directory('node_modules' in my case),We need to import map function of the Observable in your **component** using **http** service,as:

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
```

Answer (score 2):

Angular 6 - only `import 'rxjs/Rx'` did the trick for me

Answer (score 1):

Just add the line in your file,

```
import 'rxjs/Rx';
```

It will import bunch of dependencies. Tested in angular 5

Answer (score 0):

True, RxJs has separated its map operator in a separate module and now you need to explicity import it like any other operator.

`import rxjs/add/operator/map;`

and you will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Global import is safe to go with.

import 'rxjs/Rx';

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
```

will resolve your problem

I tested it in angular 5.2.0 and rxjs 5.5.2

Answer (score 0):

this is happening because you are using the rxjs and in rxjs function are not static which means you can't call them directly you have to call the methods inside the pipe and import that function from the rxjs library

But if you are using rxjs-compat then you just need to import the rxjs-compat operators

Answer (score 0):

I tried below commands and it gets fixed:

```
npm install rxjs@6 rxjs-compat@6 --save


import 'rxjs/Rx';
```

Comment: That is only to get you initially working in rxjs 6 by performing some patching for you.  It is only a short-term fix and the full rxjs 6 transition should be made.

Answer (score 0):

import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

this works for me in angular 8

Answer (score 0):

*Plus what @mlc-mlapis commented, you're mixing lettable operators and the prototype patching method. Use one or the other*.

For your case it should be

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class SwPeopleService {
    people$ = this.http.get('https://swapi.co/api/people/')
      .map((res:any) => res.results);

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {} 
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-http-observables-9nchvz?file=app%2Fsw-people.service.ts