# Angular2 Http Request returns Observable without map method

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-http

I have setup my application with `HTTP_PROVIDERS`

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [
  HTTP_PROVIDERS,
  ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
  provide(LocationStrategy, { useClass: HashLocationStrategy }),
  PostService
]);
```

and my service like

```
@Injectable()
export class PostService {
  posts = [];

  constructor(http: Http) {
    this.http = http;
  }
}
```

but when i call

```
this.http.get('/posts')
```

It returns an `Observable` which has no `map` method, it drives me crazy for hours. Im using Babel to transpile my javascript code.

Comment: They removed most of the operations from the code, you need to import the part of the library that includes that method manually. Try this: `import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';`

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34515173/angular-2-http-get-with-typescript-error-http-get-map-is-not-a-function-in/34515276#34515276

Comment: @ThierryTemplier, thanks, I closed it as a dup.  (I think this question comes up about once a week.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The newly minted [Server Communication](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html) dev guide (finally) discusses/mentions/explains this:

> The RxJS library is quite large. Size matters when we build a production application and deploy it to mobile devices. We should include only those features that we actually need.
>
> Accordingly, Angular exposes a stripped down version of `Observable` in the `rxjs/Observable` module, a version that lacks almost all operators including the ones we'd like to use here such as the `map` method...
>
> It's up to us to add the operators we need. We could add each operator, one-by-one, until we had a custom Observable implementation tuned precisely to our requirements.

E.g., as @Langley's comment above shows:

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
```

Or, if we're lazy we can just pull in the full set of operators:

```
import 'rxjs/Rx';
```