# Is Observable broken in Angular 2 Beta 3?

Tags: typescript, angular, rxjs

What used to work, no longer does...

Have an http service that returns an `Observable` from a map as in:

```
return http.get(someUrl)
    .map(res => res.json());
```

console shows the data successfully returned on the response.  However, subscribing to the returned `Observable` yields data that is `undefined`.  That is:

```
someservice.getData()
    .subscribe(data => this.data = data);
```

Not sure what is missing.

**EDIT**

data is `Undefined`, the map returns the correct json

```
http.get(someUrl)
    .map(res => res.json())
    .subscribe(data => console.log(data));
```

Comment: if you post some code stuff or plnkr it will be easy to sort out whats the error !

Comment: then why to post question ? have you any another problem ?

Comment: The return of the Map is causing the issue, you should post the entire code of this 'someservice', then we can help you. What is the return type of getData()?

Comment: no error as in no runtime error @Pardeep

Comment: I made a test and it's work for me. See this plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/jSqkGsuQTa8PqSYZlFOz?p=preview. I also tested with an application using tsc and it works...

Comment: Could you create a plunkr to reproduce the problem? Thanks!

Comment: @ThierryTemplier does your commented-out code work without the `async` pipe? Also, why the need to import `map`?

Comment: @Tim Yes, same behavior. Data are displayed in the view ;-) Not all observable operators are present for this class. See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34515173/angular-2-http-get-with-typescript-error-http-get-map-is-not-a-function-in/

Comment: Cheers @ThierryTemplie, needed to explicitly import the map function... why oh why RxJs

Comment: @TimMcNamara Great! Yes, there is a lot of operators so RxJs let you to choose what you want to include...

Answer (score 2):

Yes. There is small change in the module of `map` operator, Here is [**commit link**](https://github.com/angular/angular/commit/2a302aa)

Before while importing rxjs `operators`, below is used

```
rxjs/add/operators/map
```

now its changed to

```
rxjs/add/operator/map
```

Angular2 beta 2.0.3 [**Changelog.md**](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md)

Comment: i am already using `operator` from beta0 no error works fine !