# Two synchronous http calls using Observable

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I have a problem with Observables in Angluar2 app. Let assume hypothetical situation that I need to make two separate http calls. One call depends directly on the result of the other. The code looks like this:

```
this.http.get('http://kalafior/group/'+id)
    .map(res => res.json())
    .subscribe(group => {
        //url depends on previous call result
        this.http.get('http://kalafior/group/'+group.id+'/posts')
            .map(res => res.json())
            .subscribe((res) => {
                console.log(res);
            });
    });
```

There are nested subscribe() calls which I want to get rid of.

Comment: Same type of question, you can check it here to get a better understanding http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35268482/chaining-rxjs-observables-from-http-data-in-angular2-with-typescript?rq=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

flatMap was created exactly for this kind of scenarios.

```
this.http.get('http://kalafior/group/'+id)
    .map(res => res.json())
    .flatMap(group => this.http.get('http://kalafior/group/'+group.id+'/posts') )
    .map(res => res.json())
    .subscribe((res) => {
       console.log(res);
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

What you can do, is to take advantage of `.do()` function from Rxjs. Take a look [here](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/do.md)