# Angular2 - Use value of Observable returning method in another Observable

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, rxjs, observable

### The problem

I dont know how to use the value of the currently returned Observable of `getUserHeaders()` in my `http.get`.

### Current error

`Type 'Observable<void>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Participant[]>'`

### Expected result

Being able to use the value of my Observable returning method `getUserHeaders()` as a `headers` attribute within the `http` call. While only returning the `http` call's Observable.

### Previous code

(which worked with harcoded Headers returned by `getUserHeaders()` (so not an `Observable` or `Promise`).

```
getAllParticipants(): Observable<Array<Participant>> {
    return this.http.get('someUrl',
                {headers: this.getUserHeaders()})
           .map(response => {
               return response.json();
        });
    });
   }
```

### Current code

going by [Chaining RxJS Observables from http data in Angular2 with TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35268482/chaining-rxjs-observables-from-http-data-in-angular2-with-typescript) 's answer I came to the `flatMap` method. (**note** this code currently throws the 'current error')

```
getUserHeaders(): Observable<Headers> {
        let headers: Headers = new Headers();

        return NativeStorage.getItem("user").map(
            data => {
                headers.append('API_KEY', data.json().apiKey);
                headers.append('DEVICE_ID', data.json().deviceId);
                return headers
            }).catch( error => {
                console.log("error");
                headers.append('API_KEY', 'TEST');
                headers.append('DEVICE_ID', 'TEST');
                return headers;
            }
        );
    }

/** retrieves ALL the participants from the database */
    getAllParticipants(): Observable<Array<Participant>> {

         return this.getUserHeaders().flatMap( data => {
            return this.http.get('someUrl', {headers: data}).map(response => {
                return response.json();
            });
        });
   }
```

### plunkr (Promise instead of Observable)

http://plnkr.co/edit/A0tEB9EUodWQS6AnqrtH?p=info

(note: `Observable.fromPromise()` didn't work here so I have created the two methods returning promises -- now I want to use the value of `getUserHeaders()` inside the promise of `getParticipants()` and still return the promise/observable of `getParticipants()` and nothing from `getUserHeaders()`

Comment: What exactly is the proble here, is it typing problem? Any way,  `Array<Participant>` is wrong here because `response.json()` is `any`.

Comment: response.json() is confirmed to be an `Array<Participant>` **note:** the method `getAllParticipants` worked well before, I'm just trying to incorporate the `Headers` from the `getUserHeaders()` method

Comment: It isn't `Array<Participant>` from Typescript's perspective. And you didn't explain what is the problem.

Comment: @estus edited the question, I think I made it a bit more clear, if still unclear, please comment :)

Comment: It isn't clear what error message is and why it happens. The solution itself looks ok, [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is what the question lacks.

Comment: @estus errormessage VSCode gives me is this: `Type 'Subscription' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Participant[]>'.
  Property '_isScalar' is missing in type 'Subscription'.
(property) APICaller.http: Http`

Comment: This message suggests that `.subscribe` is done in this method. It isn't possible to resolve your issue without MCVE. The code you've posted looks ok to me but it can differ from real app

Comment: @estus, excuse me I had the wrong method in my code, this is the correct error `Type 'Observable<void>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Participant[]>'`

Comment: @estus, added plunkr, with promises instead of Observables, see question for details

Comment: Please, be specific when you're talking about errors. Runtime errors and compiler errors are totally different things.  *'Observable<void>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Participant[]>'* is type error. Returned type should be `Observable<any>`, just because `response.json()` is untyped. It's not clear what *Observable.fromPromise() didn't work here* means, and I don't see what's wrong with plunker you've posted. It is not possible to solve a problem if it isn't clear what exactly the problem is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your `getUserHeaders()` to look like:

```
getUserHeaders(): Observable<any> { return Observable.of(NativeStorage.getItem("user"); }
```

Then construct your headers object within `getParticipants()`. This way you can keep `flatMap`

Comment: where in `getParticipants` should i construct my headers?

Answer (score 0):

Personally, the solution to my problem was to use `BehaviorSubject`:

In service (source of the data):

```
private theBoolean: BehaviorSubject<boolean>;

constructor() {
    this.theBoolean = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
}

public getTheBoolean(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.theBoolean.asObservable();
}
```

To emit new value of theBoolean do smth like

```
public setTheBoolean(newValue: boolean): void {
    this.theBoolean.next(newValue);
}
```

In component (user of the data):

```
this.theService.getTheBoolean().subscribe(value => console.log(value));
```

Credit to "pashozator" on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Angular2/comments/76inse/noob_observable_on_change_of_value/)