# How to return the result received from http request inside http request in ionic 2 framework using angular 2.My code is following

Tags: angular, rest, http, typescript, ionic2

```
getUsableToken() {

    let platformName = "abc";
    let platformId = "123123";

    return this.http.get('http://localhost:17001/platform/' + platformId + '/key?name=' + platformName).map(res => res.json())
        .subscribe(data => {

                let secretKey = data.payload.platformInfo.key;

                return this.http.get('http://localhost:17001/platform/' + platformId + '/token?name=' + platformName + '&key=' + secretKey).map(res => res.json())
                    .subscribe(data => {
                        return data.payload.token;

                    }, err => {
                        console.log(err);
                    });
            },
            err => {
                console.log(err);
            });
}
```

In this code I want to return `data.payload.token`. How to do that? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is it doing right now?

Comment: It's sending an object. which is of no use?I am retrieving this value like this.jwtToken=this.authService.getUsableToken();

Comment: Ah, these requests are asynchronous.  You can't just "return" something immediately.  `getUsableToken()` is returning a Subject (from `this.http.get(...).subscribe(...);`  You could create a new Observable which contains the `data.payload.token` or a promise wrapping the same.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular2 - Use value of Observable returning method in another Observable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40613099/angular2-use-value-of-observable-returning-method-in-another-observable)

Comment: That's true, But the problem here is that I have another get request in first http get request which is creating issue.

Comment: Solved using promise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do is to make use of `flatMap` (`mergeMap`) here, since the second call is dependent on the result of the first call, so something like this:

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/mergeMap';

//....

getUsableToken() {
  return this.http.get('url')
    .map(data => {
      let secretKey = data.json().payload.platformInfo.key
      return secretKey;
    })
    // where 'key' is the parameter you need for the second call
    .flatMap(key => this.http.get('url').map(data => {
        let token = data.json().payload.token;
        return token;
    }))

}
```

and now where you subscribe you get the token:

```
doSomething() {
  this.myService.getUsableToken() 
    .subscribe(token => console.log(token))
}
```

Comment: Great! Glad to hear :) :)