# How to create Observable from function?

Tags: javascript, rx-java, rxjs, system.reactive, rxjs5

I want to call a function (synchronously) and then use its return value as an initial emission (subsequently chaining some other operators on the resulting observable).

I want to invoke this function during subscription, so I can't just use `Observable.of(() => getSomeValue())`. I've seen `bindCallback` (previously `fromCallback`) but I don't think it can be used for this task (correct me if I'm wrong). I've seen `start` static operator in v4 docs but apparently it is not implemented in v5 (and no indication that its on the way). RxJava also has `fromCallable` operator that does exactly that afaik.

Only way I could think of is like this:

```
Observable.create((observer: Observer<void>) => {
  let val = getSomeValue();
  observer.next(val);
  observer.complete();
})
```

which I think does just that. But this just seems so complicated for a simple thing that should probably have been like `Observable.fromFunction(() => getSomeValue())` And what if I want to run it asynchronously, like `start` operator does? How can I do this in the current version of RxJS?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Chaining function calls?

Comment: @ChirdeepTomar yes, I'm trying to use function as a seed and chain observable operators on its result.

Comment: look at flatmap with subscribe. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35268482/chaining-rxjs-observables-from-http-data-in-angular2-with-typescript

Comment: @ChirdeepTomar I think you have not read my question carefully... My target function (that I'm trying to start observable chain with) is not returning an observable, it just returns ordinary value (say string), so I can't use `flatmap` (or any other Observable operator) on it obviously.

Answer (score 27):

I tend to avoid any explicit use of `Observable.create` where ever possible, because generally it is a source of bugs to have to manage not just your event emission but also your teardown logic.

You can use [`Observable.defer`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-defer) instead. It accepts a function that returns an `Observable` or an `Observable-like` thing (read: Promise, Array, Iterators). So if you have a function that returns an async thing it is as easy as:

```
Observable.defer(() => doSomethingAsync());
```

If you want this to work with a synchronous result then do:

```
Observable.defer(() => Observable.of(doSomethingSync()));
```

Note: That like `create` this will rerun the function on each subscription. This is different then say the result of `Observable.bindCallback` which stores the function call result without re-executing the function. So if you need that sort of behavior you will need to use the appropriate `multicasting` operator.

Answer (score 5):

An implementation of a `fromFunction$` that I used in my project:

```
function fromFunction$<T>(factory: () => T): Observable<T> {
    return Observable.create((observer: Subscriber<T>) => {
        try {
            observer.next(factory());
            observer.complete();
        } catch (error) {
            observer.error(error);
        }
    });
}
```

Used like:

```
fromFunction$(() => 0).subscribe((value) => console.log(`Value is '${value}'`), null, () => console.log('Completed'));
fromFunction$(() => [1, 2, 3]).subscribe((value) => console.log(`Value is '${value}'`), null, () => console.log('Completed'));
fromFunction$(() => { throw 'Something' }).subscribe(null, (error) => console.error(`Error: ${error}`));
```

Gives:

```
Value is '0'
Completed

Value is '1,2,3'
Completed

Error: Something
```

Until such implementation exists.

Answer (score 3):

Actually I think the best option is using `Observable.create` because it's the most universal solution for both synchronous and asynchronous initial values.

If you're sure you'll use a synchronous function you can use [`startWith()`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-startWith) operator (this makes sence only if return value from `getSomeValue()` should be the same for all Observers).

Using `Observable.bindCallback` as a source Observable is of course doable however I personally recommend to avoid it because it makes your code very hard to understand and it's usually not necessary because you can use just `Observable.create`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `of` like this:

```
//anonymous fn
of((() => {...})())


//declared fn
of(myFunc())
```