# Angular 2 multiple http call at once

Tags: angular, typescript

Below i am using API to get country region from server using Observable and that country code is saved into **sessionStorage()**:

```
let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: this.headers });
      return this.http.get(this.backendUrl + pathName, options)
                  .map((res: Response) => {
                        return res.json();
                    })
                  .catch(e => {
                      if (e.status === 401) {
                          this.router.navigateByUrl('/error');
                          return Observable.throw('Unauthorized');
                      }
                 });
```

and below is my another code where i want to use that country region code which is stored in **sessionStorage()** in post request:

```
let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: this.headers });
      body_val['hash_value'] = root.hashValue;
      body_val['region'] = <!-- Region -->;
      body_val['client_id'] = 'ABC';
      body_val['users_id'] = this.users_id;
      if (localStorage.getItem('userdata'))  {
          let user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userdata'));
          body_val['users_id'] = user.userdata.id;
          body_val['userid'] = user.userdata.id;
      }

      return this.http.post(root.apiUrl + pathName, body_val , options)
                   .map((res: Response) => {
                        return res.json();
                    })
                   .catch(e => {
                      if (e.code === 404) {
                           this.router.navigateByUrl('/error');
                           return Observable.throw('Unauthorized');
                      }
                   });
```

On first time when i load the page, i am getting ***null*** but in second time load the page i am able to get the value of **sessionStorage()** .How i can achieve first API call data is second API and on first page load.

Comment: they can't happen both at once and one after another. You need to make your send call wait for the first one to finish.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Chaining RxJS Observables from http data in Angular2 with TypeScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35268482/chaining-rxjs-observables-from-http-data-in-angular2-with-typescript)

Comment: above link does not works. can you suggest me how i can achieve this thing.