# How can I chain some asynchronous operations like then() with Observables

Tags: angular, rxjs

I create a user and now I want to login the user after this operation. I was using toPromise() but now I just want to use observables:

```
    return this.httpClient.post('/user', user)
                          .map(response => response.json() as User)
                          .catch(this.handleError);
```

With promises I could do this

```
return this.create(data)
           .then(function(user: User) {
              return self.login(user.email, user.password);
           })
           .then(function(resp: loginStuff) {
              // set session
           })
```

How can I chain with observables?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Chaining RxJS Observables from http data in Angular2 with TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35268482/chaining-rxjs-observables-from-http-data-in-angular2-with-typescript)

Comment: what are you expecting?

Comment: Not sure what you want. There is 'do' https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/utility/do.html and 'Observable.fromPromise' https://stackoverflow.com/a/39319314/495157