# Firebase-Angular returning value outside loop

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase

I am new at Angular and using Firebase. When I check user login my function always return 0 even I did correct checking. My problem is my return value comes from outside.

```
 checkLog(mail: string, password: string): number {
        let isTrue = 0;
        this.http.get(exampleJson).subscribe(resData => {
            for (let data in resData) {
                this.http.get<User_model>(exampleJson' + data + '/.json').subscribe(res2Data => {
                    console.log('Name = ', res2Data.user_name, 'Password = ', res2Data.password);
                    if (mail === res2Data.user_name && password === res2Data.password) {
                        isTrue = 1;
                    }
                })
            }
        });
        return isTrue;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main reason is that you are making several asynchronous HTTP calls in your function, which take time to process.

When `checkLog` is called the workflow is the following :

- `let isTrue = 0;` is called
- `this.http` is called asynchronously which means it will take some time to process
- `return isTrue;` is called right after

Your variable `isTrue` has no time to be processed and obviously return 0 because your HTTP calls did not process your variable in time.

One of the solution for your problem can be found [on this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53817629/wait-for-asynchronous-functions-to-finish-in-angular).