# Set Observable value to an exportable variable. Angular v6

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

My services

```
search (packageName: string, refresh = false): Observable<PackageInfo>
   {
    const options = createHttpOptions(packageName, refresh);
    this.searchResults = this.http.get(searchUrl + packageName, options) as Observable<PackageInfo>;
    return this.searchResults
  }
```

I can do

```
this.searchResults.subscribe(repoUrl => console.log(repoUrl.repos_url))
```

This will display the url that is in my Observable. I need to save the repos_url, so I can make a second http.get call. I am not sure how to do this. My thoughts where to save the subscribe, but that returns undefined in the console.log.Which means nothing is returning from what I read it is because value only exist as long as the Observable is active. I am stuck right now. I got my Profile search component working and my Repo list component, but I need the Profile component to pass the repo url to the Repo List component.

profile-search.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpErrorHandler, HandleError } from '../error-handler.service';

export interface PackageInfo {
  login: string
  name: string
  avatar_url: string
  repos_url: string

}

export const searchUrl = 'https://api.github.com/users/';

const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'x-refresh':  'true'
  })
};

function createHttpOptions(packageName: string, refresh = false) {
    const headerMap = refresh ? {'x-refresh': 'true'} : {};
    const headers = new HttpHeaders(headerMap) ;
    return { headers };
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class PackageSearchService {
  searchResults: Observable<PackageInfo>;
  private handleError: HandleError;

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    httpErrorHandler: HttpErrorHandler
   ) {
    this.handleError = httpErrorHandler.createHandleError('Service');
  }

  search (packageName: string, refresh = false): Observable<PackageInfo>
   {
    const options = createHttpOptions(packageName, refresh);
    this.searchResults = this.http.get(searchUrl + packageName, options) as Observable<PackageInfo>;
    return this.searchResults
  }

}
```

My first thought was to create a blank variable with string type.

```
export class PackageSearchService {
      searchResults: Observable<PackageInfo>;
      private handleError: HandleError;
      repoUrl: string;  <== new

      constructor(
        private http: HttpClient,
        httpErrorHandler: HttpErrorHandler
       ) {
        this.handleError = httpErrorHandler.createHandleError('Service');
      }

      search (packageName: string, refresh = false): Observable<PackageInfo>
       {
        const options = createHttpOptions(packageName, refresh);
        this.searchResults = this.http.get(searchUrl + packageName, options) as Observable<PackageInfo>;
        this.repoUrl = this.searchResults.subscribe(userRepo => userRepo.repo_url)
        return this.searchResults
      }
```

repo-list.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { RepoListComponent } from './repo-list.services';
import { PackageSearchService } from '../profile-search/profile-search.service';
import { RepoList } from '../repoList';
import { Observable, Subscription } from 'rxjs';



@Component({
  selector: 'repo-list',
  templateUrl: './repo-list.html',
  styleUrls: ['../profile-search/profile-search.component.css']
})

export class UsersRepoComponent implements OnInit {
  repo: RepoList[] = [];


  constructor( private repoService : RepoListComponent,
    private searchService: PackageSearchService){}



  ngOnInit(){
    this.getRepoList(); 
}


  getRepoList(): void {
    this.repoService.getRepoReturn()
    .subscribe(repo => this.repo = repo);
  }

  getRepoUrl(){
    this.searchService.repoUrl;
  }

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to return value from function which has Observable subscription inside?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38291783/how-to-return-value-from-function-which-has-observable-subscription-inside)

Comment: Post what you tried, and we'll explain why it doesn't work, and how to make it work. It's most probably related to asynchrony, and probably has nothing to do with "because value only exist as long as the Observable is active".

Comment: ok so I first tried to set the scriber to a blank string

Comment: `repoUrl: string  this.repoUrl = this.searchResults.subscribe(repoUrl => console.log(repoUrl.repos_url))`

Comment: Edit your question, and post all the relevant code in the question. And tell precisely what you want to achieve.

Comment: I also tried Behaviour Subject with no success.

Comment: I want to get the repo_url from the observable, so I can pass it into another http.get call in another service.

Comment: I can add link to git repo if you like.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a constructor in you services class having url which can be used further. Below is the snippet

```
repoUrl:string

constructor(private httpClient:HttpClient) {
  this.repoUrl ="http://localhost:3990/"
}

getProjects(packageName:string):Observable<Project[]>{
   return this.httpClient.get(this.repoUrl+packageName)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't make much sense:

1. the arguments you pass to createHttpOptions() are not used anywhere
2. You assign the result of .subscribe(...) to a variable of type `string`, but `subscribe()` returns a Subscription, not a string. Observables are used because http calls are **asynchronous** you can't expect the result to be available immediately after you've called `httpClient.get()`. It will only be availeble later, when the response is available, and the observable will then notify its subscribers with the result.
3. You try to use the `searchService.repoUrl` field without ever calling the method that initializes it.

To chain asynchronous calls returning Observables, the easiest way is to use the `switchMap()` operator:

```
getRepoUrl().pipe(
  switchMap(url => getSomethingUsingTheUrl(url))
).subscribe(something => doWhateverYouWant(something));
```

The disadvantage of this is that everythime you want to load something, you will first make a request to get the repo url, then a second request to get something.

You can only get the URL once and cache it using a single observable using the `shareReplay` operator:

```
class UrlService {
  url$: Observable<string>;

  constructor(httpClient: HttpClient) {
    this.url$ = httpClient.get(...).pipe(shareReplay());
  }
}
```

and in your component:

```
this.urlService.url$.pipe(
  switchMap(url => getSomethingUsingTheUrl(url))
).subscribe(something => doWhateverYouWant(something));
```

Observables are hard to grasp, but you definitely need to take time to learn them if you want to use Angular correctly and efficiently. The first step is to understand asynchrony, which is the main readon why Observables exist in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

So JB, I am trying to follow your example close. When I did

url$: Observable;

I got an error, that this.url$ is object and not assignable to string, so I did

```
url$: Observable<object>;
```

I also had to combine my url and search term into one string.

```
export class PackageSearchService {
  searchResults: Observable<PackageInfo>;
  private handleError: HandleError;

  url$: Observable<Object>;
  fulluserUrl: string;

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    httpErrorHandler: HttpErrorHandler
   ) {
    this.handleError = httpErrorHandler.createHandleError('Service');
    this.url$ = http.get(this.fulluserUrl).pipe(shareReplay());
  }

  search (packageName: string, refresh = false): Observable<PackageInfo>
   {
    const options = createHttpOptions(packageName, refresh);
    this.searchResults = this.http.get(searchUrl + packageName, options) as Observable<PackageInfo>;
    return this.searchResults
  }

  userRepo (packageName: string)
  {
    this.fulluserUrl = searchUrl + packageName;
    return this.fulluserUrl;
  }

}
```

As for component example

```
this.urlService.url$.pipe(
  switchMap(url => getSomethingUsingTheUrl(url))
).subscribe(something => doWhateverYouWant(something));
```

I have a similar switchMap in my profile-search.component

```
switchMap(packageName =>
        this.searchService.search(packageName, this.withRefresh)
      )
      ).subscribe(
        user => this.user = user
      );
```

just not sure what getSomethingUsingTheUrl or doWhateverYouWant should be or how I should edit

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to chain 2 Observables calls one after the other, using the result of the first observable in the second observable call, FlatMap is what you seek: [Chaining RxJS Observables from http data in Angular2 with TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35268482/chaining-rxjs-observables-from-http-data-in-angular2-with-typescript#answer-35268597)

If you are trying to save the url string for other non-immediate calls, a ReplaySubject inside a service is what I've used in the past.

Quick Note: you can return this.http.get(...) directly, no need to parameterize as 'searchResults'.

Comment: I understand that I will need to add `const repoUrl = new Rx.ReplaySubject(1)` because I want the last value from my `export interface PackageInfo {
  login: string
  name: string
  avatar_url: string
  repos_url: string
  
}`, but I am not sure how to `repoUrl.subscribe` to my repo_url that is in my `this.searchResults.subscribe(userUrl => userUrl.repos_url)`

Comment: Examples I have seen `subject.subscribe((data) => { console.log("Subscriber A:" + data):});` so how would I `this.searchResults.subscribe(repoUrl => {repoUrl.subscribe(repoUrl.repos_url)})` I just not sure how to feed the url into the ReplaySubject.

Comment: First, lets assume you want to get the response from the search() function, extra the repos_url, and use it in another async call immediately.

To do this, you could chain operators in a single command: 

`this.search().flatmap((repoUrl: any) => someFuncThatReturnsObservable(repoUrl.repos_url)).subscribe((data:  any) => do something with the data));`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, thanks to Keenan and JB. I was able to resolve this by using tap and using BehaviorSubject.

MyService

```
export class ProfileSearchService {
  profile: BehaviorSubject<ProfileInfo> = new BehaviorSubject({ login: '', name: '', avatar_url: '', repos_url: '' });
  repos: BehaviorSubject<any[]> = new BehaviorSubject([]);

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.profile.subscribe(({ repos_url }) => {
      if (repos_url) {
        // http request, set repoFetch to return value
        this.http.get(repos_url).pipe(
          tap(repos => this.repos.next(repos as any[]))
        ).subscribe();;
      }
    });
  }

  search (packageName: string) {
    this.http.get(searchUrl + packageName).pipe(
      tap(user => {
        this.profile.next(user as ProfileInfo)
      })
    ).subscribe();
  }
}
```

MyComponent

```
export class UsersRepoComponent implements OnInit {
  repo$: Observable<any>;

  constructor(private searchService: ProfileSearchService){}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.repo$ = this.searchService.repos;
  }

}
```

Also, thanks to [Corey Pyle](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9486626/corey-pyle) for holding my hand and walking me through this.