# ngOnInit() method not working as expected

Tags: angular

I am working on the frontend of a Web app with Angular. I have an issue with the `ngOnInit()` method. This is my component.ts file:

```
export class TimesheetComponent implements OnInit {
  timesheetInfo: ITimesheetInfo;
  month: number;
  year: number;
  employeeEmail: string;
  dataSource: ITimesheetRow[] = [];

  constructor(private translate: TranslateService, private notify: NotificationService, private timesheetService: TimesheetService) {}

    getTimesheetInfo(employeeEmail: string, month: number, year: number): void {
      this.timesheetService.getTimesheetInfo(employeeEmail, month, year).subscribe({
        next: (data): void => {
          this.timesheetInfo = data;
          console.log(this.timesheetInfo);
        },
        error: (err): void => {
          if(err.status != 401) {
            this.notify.error(this.translate.instant('ERRORS.GENERAL_ERROR'))
          }
        }
      });
    }
    
    getRows(): void {
      this.timesheetService.getCurrentRows(this.timesheetInfo.id).subscribe({
        next: (data): void => {
            this.dataSource = data;
          },
        error: (err): void => {
          if (err.status != 401) {
            this.notify.error(this.translate.instant('ERRORS.GENERAL_ERROR'));
          }
        }
      });
    }

  ngOnInit(): void {

    this.employeeEmail = 'mymail@gmail.com';
    this.month = 1;
    this.year = 2021;

    this.getTimesheetInfo(this.employeeEmail, this.month, this.year);
    
    this.getRows();
  }

}
```

The variable `timesheetInfo` is displayed correctly with the new values (including the id) in the console, as asked inside the `getTimesheetInfo()` method. However, I still get this error:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
    at TimesheetComponent.getRows (timesheet.component.ts:73)
    at TimesheetComponent.ngOnInit (timesheet.component.ts:340)
```

This is about the field `this.timesheetInfo.id`, which I use in the `getRows()` method: this method is used inside the `ngOnInit()` method. So it seems that the variable `timesheetInfo` isn't updated inside the `ngOnInit()` method. How is it possible?

Comment: you should chain your calls and make sure the second call is excecuted only when the first one is completed : take a look to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35268482/chaining-rxjs-observables-from-http-data-in-angular2-with-typescript

Comment: edit your questions title, this problem has nothing to do with `ngOnInit()`

Comment: @lucia please change the title of the question, this is not related to ngOnInit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by the time you are calling the `getRows()` the value of `this.timesheetInfo` is not set yet

you should either use `async` and `await` or call your `getRows()` method in the callback function of `getTimesheetInfo()`

```js
    getTimesheetInfo(employeeEmail: string, month: number, year: number): void {
      this.timesheetService.getTimesheetInfo(employeeEmail, month, year).subscribe({
        next: (data): void => {
          this.timesheetInfo = data;
          console.log(this.timesheetInfo);

          // here, after you set this.timesheetInfo
          this.getRows();

        },
        error: (err): void => {
          if(err.status != 401) {
            this.notify.error(this.translate.instant('ERRORS.GENERAL_ERROR'))
          }
        }
      });
    }
```

Comment: I didn't want to confuse you with async/await but consider learning them cause they are the better and more readable way of doing this

Answer (score 0):

the recommended way of achieving this is by using the rxjs operators,
you could do it like this.

```
    getTimesheetInfo(employeeEmail: string, month: number, year: number): void {
    this.timesheetService.getTimesheetInfo(employeeEmail, month, year)
      .pipe
      (
        tap(timeSheetInfo => {
          this.timesheetInfo = timeSheetInfo;
        }),
        switchMap(() => {
          return this.timesheetService.getCurrentRows(this.timesheetInfo.id);
        }),
        tap(data => {
          this.dataSource = data;
        }),
        catchError(err => {
          if (err.status != 401) {
            this.notify.error(this.translate.instant('ERRORS.GENERAL_ERROR'));
          }
          return EMPTY;
        })
      )
      .subscribe();
  }
```