# angular rxjs: handle multiple http requests

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I have following pseudocode

```
objects = [obj1, obj2, obj3]    
for obj in objects {
user: http.get(obj1.user_id)
product: http.get(obj1.product_id)
}.subscribe(results => {

do something with results

})
```

What I want here is that, I loop through an array of objects and for each object get related user and product and then subscribe to do something with the user and product. How can I do that?

Comment: you can try to check this info about with observables: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35268482/chaining-rxjs-observables-from-http-data-in-angular2-with-typescript or you can check this info about promises:  https://javascript.info/promise-chaining

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use RxJS [`forkJoin`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/forkJoin) along with [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to trigger multiple observables in parallel.

```js
const objects = [obj1, obj2, obj3];

forkJoin(
  objects.map(obj =>           // <-- `Array#map` function
    forkJoin({
      user: http.get(obj.user_id)
      product: http.get(obj.product_id)
    })
  )
).subscribe({
  next: (res) => {
    console.log(res);
    // use `res`
  },
  error: (err) => {}
});


/*
output in subscription: 
[
  { 
    user: result from `http.get(obj1.user_id)`,
    product: result from `http.get(obj1.product_id)`,
  },
  { 
    user: result from `http.get(obj2.user_id)`,
    product: result from `http.get(obj2.product_id)`,
  },
  { 
    user: result from `http.get(obj3.user_id)`,
    product: result from `http.get(obj3.product_id)`,
  }
]
*/
```

Comment: How to console.log the results inside subscribe?

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [`zip()` operator](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/zip) to combine your requests and execute some code once every request has finished:

```
const sourceOne = http.get(obj1.product_id);
const sourceTwo = http.get(obj2.product_id);

zip(sourceOne, sourceTwo).subscribe(val => {
    // do something
});
```