# BehaviorSubject filter is not a function?

Tags: angular, rxjs

Spend some time trying to figure out why my plunker doesn't work :(

https://plnkr.co/edit/JHODQeWQtYmz4UkYzFds?p=preview

error append on following line

```
let load = this.actions$.filter (action => return action.type==START_LOADING);
```

actions$ is defined like this :

```
private actions$ : BehaviorSubject<Action> = new BehaviorSubject<Action>({type: null, payload: null});
```

and I import this

```
import { Subject } from "rxjs/subject";
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/subject/BehaviorSubject';
```

in debugger of Chrome, I see that some functions are available (map, lift, scan, etc) but not filter.

Somebody know why filter is not available on BehaviorSubject ? I imagine  that is a simple mistake but I don't find it ;)

Answer (score 14):

I think that you should import the `filter` operator:

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/filter';
```

Here is your updated plunkr with this import: https://plnkr.co/edit/37JEG4aQ7qmQuaPchB4Z?p=preview.

See this question for more details:

- [Angular 2 HTTP GET with TypeScript error http.get(...).map is not a function in [null]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34515173/angular-2-http-get-with-typescript-error-http-get-map-is-not-a-function-in/34515276#34515276)