# Error : .map() is not a function

Tags: http, xmlhttprequest, angular

Trying to subscribe to the parsed response of HTTP - GET from the component. Getting a error saying .map is not a function whether used from HTTPService or from the component class.

```
Httpdemo.getResponse().map(res => res.json()).subscribe((cities)=>{ 
   this.cities = cities.cities;          
   console.log(this.cities);
});
```

But the following works:

```
Httpdemo.getResponse().subscribe((cities)=>{ 
    this.cities = JSON.parse(cities._body).cities;          
    console.log(this.cities);
});
```

The parsing also does not work in the Httpdemo service.

```
return this.http.get('./app/cities.json').map(res => res.json())
```

What is wrong with the usage here in my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to import the map operator for Observable as described below:

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
```

By default not all operators are included.

See this answer for more details:

- [Angular 2 HTTP GET with TypeScript error http.get(...).map is not a function in [null]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34515173/angular-2-http-get-with-typescript-error-http-get-map-is-not-a-function-in/34515276#34515276)

Answer (score 2):

In general, I'd suggest to import below library if you are not interested to load/target individual Rxjs operators.

Use,

> ***import 'rxjs/Rx';***