# Angular2 @ TypeScript error rxjs/Subject:: filtering when user stops typing

Tags: typescript, angular, rxjs

I am using Angular 2.0.0-beta.0 and TypeScript 1.7.5. while trying to change the clever filter on:

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html#!#more-observables

The "clever" filter should only do something when the user stops typing.

I get compile error:

```
Error:(30, 20) TS2345: Argument of type '(term: string) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(x: {}, ix: number) => Observable<any>'. Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'Observable<any>'.
```

Run time error:

```
EXCEPTION: Error during instantiation of Test!.  
ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: TypeError: this._searchTermStream.debounceTime is not a function
```

test.ts

```
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {Observable}        from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {Subject}           from 'rxjs/Subject';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
        <h3>Test</h3>
        Filter basic <input #filterBasic (keyup)="searchBasic(filterBasic.value)"/><br>
        Filter clever <input #filterClever (keyup)="searchClever(filterClever.value)"/>
        <ul>
            <li *ngFor="#contact of contactsFilter">{{contact}}</li>
        </ul>
    `
})

export class Test {

    public contacts: string[] = ["John", "Kaen", "Kath", "Joop", "Joost"];
    public contactsFilter: string[] = this.contacts;

    private _searchTermStream = new Subject<string>();

    private items:Observable<string[]> = this._searchTermStream
        .debounceTime(300)
        .distinctUntilChanged()
        .switchMap((term: string) => this.contactFilter(term));

    constructor () {}

    searchBasic(term: string) {
        console.log("Filter Basic " + term + " called");
        this.contactFilter(term);
    }

    searchClever(term: string) {
        console.log("Filter Clever " + term + " called");
        this._searchTermStream.next(term);
    }

    contactFilter(term: string) {
        this.contactsFilter = this.contacts.filter(item => (item.indexOf(term) >= 0))
    }
}

bootstrap(Test);
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base href="/">
    <script src="angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="typescript/lib/typescript.js"></script>
    <script src="systemjs/dist/system.js"></script>
    <script src="angular2/bundles/router.dev.js"></script>
    <script src="rxjs/bundles/Rx.js"></script>
    <script src="angular2/bundles/angular2.js"></script>
    <script src="angular2/bundles/http.dev.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script>
      System.config({
        transpiler: 'typescript',
        typescriptOptions: { emitDecoratorMetadata: true },
        packages: {'components': {defaultExtension: 'ts'}}
      });
      System.import('components/test')
            .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <my-app>Loading...</my-app>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: After solving runtime and compile error following Sasxa's solution the "searchClever" function doesn't wait (debounceTime 300 ms) for the user to stop typing and fires the function straight after the first "keyup" event

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are getting runtime error because `Observables` by default come with just a few operators. You have to explicitly import them:

```
// in test.ts
import 'rxjs/add/operator/debounceTime';
```

or:

```
// in bootstrap.ts
import 'rxjs/Rx';
```

Compile error is because the signature doesn't match to the one from docs. Change few lines:

```
.switchMap((term: any, i) => this.contactFilter(term));
```

and

```
contactFilter(term: string) {
    this.contactsFilter = this.contacts.filter(item => (item.indexOf(term) >= 0))
    // Return some observable to make editor happy
    // Could be something useful even (;
    // Or just like this:
    return Observable.of(true);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the runtime error, you didn't import the debounceTime operator, as described below:

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/debounceTime';
```

Operators aren't included by default, you need to add them one by one according to your needs.

See this answer fore more details:

- [Angular 2 HTTP GET with TypeScript error http.get(...).map is not a function in [null]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34515173/angular-2-http-get-with-typescript-error-http-get-map-is-not-a-function-in/34515276#34515276)