# angular 2 conditional chaining of observables

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a modal popup, which I am coding such that when an `open()` function is called, it returns an observable. Any subscriber will then get an object with a property indicating what button was pressed in the modal or whether it was closed, etc.

If a 'success' button is pressed, I want to make a http call, which in turn also returns an observable! How would I combine these two observables? In angular 1 with promises I can return promises from promises, so I would do something like

```
 var promise = modal.open()
                    .then(function(res) { 
                        if (res.success) {
                            return httpService.get(); // also returns a promise
                        }

                        return res;
                    });
```

how would I do something like this for observables?

Comment: With Observables you can also return Observables. It's exactly the same logic with maybe `map` instead of `then`.

Comment: Thanks I'll give that a shot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can leverage observable operators to build an asynchronous data flow. In you case, the `switchMap` operator:

```
var observable = modalObservable.switchMap(() => {
  return return httpService.get(); // also returns an observable
});
```

Be careful to import the operators you need since they aren't by default (see this question: [Angular 2 HTTP GET with TypeScript error http.get(...).map is not a function in [null]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34515173/angular-2-http-get-with-typescript-error-http-get-map-is-not-a-function-in/34515276#34515276)):

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';
```

You could have a look at the following article and presentation for more details:

- The introduction to Reactive Programming you've been missing - https://gist.github.com/staltz/868e7e9bc2a7b8c1f754
- Everything is a stream - http://slides.com/robwormald/everything-is-a-stream

Comment: Ok, but what about only returning the http observable conditionally? Based on a value from the modal observable subscription?

Comment: In fact, within the `switchMap`, you will receive this value as first parameter... So you can use it to create the new observable to return.

Comment: Ok thanks, but sorry one more question :) so with switchmap you can return a value (an object) or an observable?

Comment: If you want to return an object, use the `map` operator. With `switchMap`, you can return an observable that will take part of the processing chain... In your case, the `httpService.get()` will be executed and the response will be then handled in the asynchronous processing chain (for example received in a `subscribe` method).

Comment: Ok well that's the problem! I need to combine the two like in my promise example. Can I do something like `modalObservable.switchMap((r) => {
  if (r.success) { return httpService.get(); } else { Observable.from(r); }
});`

Comment: Yes but don't forget the return within the `else` ;-)

Comment: observable.from or observable.of ?