# Basic service test

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

I have a service like :

login.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from 'angular2/core';
import { Http, Response, Headers } from 'angular2/http';
import { Config } from '../common/config';

@Injectable()
export class LoginService {

    constructor(public http: Http) { }
    response: JSON;
...

    getAuthenticate( username, password ) {
        let headers = new Headers();
        const REST_BASE_URL = Config.GET_REST_BASE_URL;
        let query = '?userid=' + username + ' +&action=authenticate&password=' + password;
        headers.set('Accept', 'application/json');
        return this.http.get(REST_BASE_URL + query, {
        headers: headers
         }).map((res: Response) => res.json());
    }
}
```

I need to write a test for e.g. getAutenticate() method. No idea how I should inject that Http (mock-up vs real rest service). Here is my starting point:

```
import { it, describe, expect, inject, beforeEachProviders} from 'angular2/testing';
import {Http} from 'angular2/http';
import { LoginService } from './login.service';

class MockLoginService extends LoginService {
    // todo something
}

describe('login service', () => {
    beforeEachProviders(() => [
        provide(TestService, {useClass: MockLoginService}), Http
  ]);

    // beforeEachProviders(() => [LoginService, Http]);
    it('should find credentials', inject([LoginService], (myService:MockLoginService) => {
        console.log('HERE ', myService.getAutenticate('user1', 'pass1'));
        expect(true).toBe(true);
    }));
});
```

What would be a good approach ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In fact to test your `LoginService` you need to mock its dependencies and not the service itself. In this case, you need to replace the `XHRBackend` class by the `MockBackend` one.

```
beforeEachProviders(() => {
    return [
  HTTP_PROVIDERS,
  provide(XHRBackend, { useClass: MockBackend }),
        HttpService
    ];
});
```

Then you can inject the `XHRBackend` and subscribe on its `connections` property to intercept requests and return your own responses.

Here is a sample with a service called `HttpService`:

```
it('test HTTP service', inject([XHRBackend, HttpService, Injector], (mockBackend, httpService, injector) => {
    mockBackend.connections.subscribe(
        (connection: MockConnection) => {
            connection.mockRespond(new Response(
                new ResponseOptions({
                    body: ['some content']
                })));
    });

    httpService.getMethod().subscribe(
        items => {
            expect(items).toEqual(['test']);
        },
        () => {
            console.log('error');
        });
}));
```

The `HttpService` could be the following:

```
@Injectable()
export class HttpService {
  constructor(private http:Http) {
  }

  getMethod() {
    return this.http.get('/test').map(res => res.json());
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you again, Thierry, I tried your example : the problem is I get the error: Failed: httpService.getMethod is not a function ...

Comment: And you have a `getMethod` method on your `HttpService` class?

Comment: So I have no idea what I did but: based on your answer I tried https://github.com/krimple/angular2-webpack-demo-routing-and-http . I had same issue . Then I looked at the Service and I noticed there is an import there import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'; I added that to teh service and worked !

Comment: Great! Pleased to hear that! Yes you need to import it explicitly. See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34515173/angular-2-http-get-with-typescript-error-http-get-map-is-not-a-function-in/34515276#34515276.

Comment: I come from a slightly different background (ExtJS) and this seem strange to me : to have something into the class you want to test in order to be able to test it ...mmm.

Comment: What do you mean by "have something into the class you want to test"?