# How to use Observables operators with EventEmitter (FormModel.valueChanges) in Angular2

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular2-forms, rxjs5

I'm trying to use some simple operators on a EventEmitter (from a FormModel.valueChanges) but I don't know how it's suppose to be done.

The class EventEmitter extends from Subject 
`export declare class EventEmitter<T> extends Subject<T>` 
so I tried several things:

`this.patientForm.valueChanges.debounceTime(400)`
`this.patientForm.valueChanges.source.debounceTime(400)`
`this.patientForm.valueChanges.asObservable().debounceTime(400)`
`Observable.create(this.patientForm.valueChanges).debounceTime(400)`

tried in the constructor and in ngOnInit 
the source is always undefined and the operators don't exist in the class.

I have this import `import {Observable} from 'rxjs';` could be something with that?

(what I'm trying to do is save the form state in a Redux store, but don't want to do it in every keystroke)

Comment: Looks like a dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34515173/angular-2-http-get-with-typescript-error-http-get-map-is-not-a-function-in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Günter stated, operators aren't by default included

To import the `Observable` class, just use the following. In this case, you will have all the operators within the `Observable` class:

```
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';
```

To only have the `debounceTime` operator, you could use this:

```
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/debounceTime';
```

Then the right way to use the `debounceTime` operator is:

```
this.patientForm.valueChanges.debounceTime(400).subscribe((val) => {
  (...)
});
```

See this article for more details:

- https://jaxenter.com/reactive-programming-http-and-angular-2-124560.html

Comment: `import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';` didn't work (I think the operators aren't added at that point), instead I used `import 'rxjs/Rx';`. Is that a bad idea?

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the operators

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/debounceTime'
```

or all of them at once

```
import 'rxjs/Rx';
```