# Migration from Angular2 beta1 to Angular2 beta15 - .map() error

Tags: typescript, angular, rxjs, rxjs5, typescript1.8

I'm trying to migrate a project from Angular2 **beta1** to Angular2 **beta15** and I have some issues.

I have error message : **'map' property does not exists on 'Observable< Response >'**

Example of code with this error :

```
import { Injectable } from 'angular2/core';
import { Http, Response, Headers } from 'angular2/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { HelperModule } from './helpers.module';
import { BlogPost } from './model';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

/**
 * Service dealing with blog data
 */
@Injectable()
export class DataService {

    constructor(private http: Http) { }

    /**
     * Call API to list available blog posts
     */
    listBlogPosts() {
        return this.http.get(HelperModule.UrlBuilder.BuildPostListUrl()).map(res => (<Response>res).json());
    }

}
```

Code is available here : https://github.com/AdrienTorris/AspNet5Angular2Playground

EDIT : I'm using *rxjs 5.0.0-beta6* and *typescript 1.8.10*, targetting *es6*

Comment: map decorator works with rxjs 5.0.0-beta2

Answer (score 1):

Try using the latest version of Typescript (1.9) to compile your code. Module augmentation is bugged in some minor versions of TS 1.8. RXJS changed the way it defines its modules after 5.0.0-beta2.

You can try the nightly build using: `npm install -g typescript@next`

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the `map` operator:

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
```

or all operators:

```
import 'rxjs/Rx';
```

See this question:

- [Angular 2 HTTP GET with TypeScript error http.get(...).map is not a function in [null]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34515173/angular-2-http-get-with-typescript-error-http-get-map-is-not-a-function-in/34515276#34515276)

Comment: map operator is imported. I test with import all.

Comment: Mum. Is the same when using `import 'rxjs/Rx';`? I created a plunkr with beta15 and it works for me: https://plnkr.co/edit/7Psl5Q0DGFLxlb4DH0lO?p=preview. I get rxjs from code.angularjs.org so I don't exactly know the version. I guess that it's rxjs beta2 as described in https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html. Do you have the same error when using this version with angular2 beta15?

Comment: with rxjs 5.0.0-beta2 it works, but I have some other problems with the migration.

Comment: Okay great! Which problems?

Comment: Error Token must be defined! at Function.Injector.resolve (http://localhost:48900/js/angular2/angular2.dev.js:11152:25)
    at Injector.resolveAndCreateChild (http://localhost:48900/js/angular2/angular2.dev.js:11198:40)
    at http://localhost:48900/js/angular2/angular2.dev.js:12529:42

Comment: Are you targeting es5 or es6 ?

Comment: Do you know which token isn't defined?

Comment: with es5 I have so many errors ...like 'Map is undefined' or 'Iterator is undefined'. With es6 solution builds.
For the token I don't know, I don't use token in the application and all worked before the migration

Comment: Do you add the polyfills files?

Comment: For the token, perhaps you could enable "pause on exceptions" in dev tools (Sources tab). This way, you will be able to debug this...

Comment: Yes I add polyfills file, this is my gulp task for angular: var angularJs = [
    './node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js',
    './node_modules/angular2/bundles/router.dev.js',
    './node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js',
    './node_modules/angular2/bundles/http.dev.js'
];