# How to get arrays from .json Ionic 2 Angular 2

Tags: arrays, json, angular, ionic2, angular2-template

In applications where there is an array, and with it another 7 arrays, I can't manage to show it in the template. Can someone please tell me how to get arrays from json?

Thank you all!

`channel.json`, comming with the name `channel`:

```
{
  "version": 3.1,
  "get": true,
  "programms1": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "img": "image.png",
      "name": "name",
      "about": "about"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "img": "image.png",
      "name": "name",
      "about": "about"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "img": "image.png",
      "name": "name",
      "about": "about"
    }
  ],
  "programms2": [
    {
            "id": 1,
      "img": "image.png",
      "name": "name",
      "about": "about"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "img": "image.png",
      "name": "name",
      "about": "about"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "img": "image.png",
      "name": "name",
      "about": "about"
    }
  ],
  "programms3": [
    {
            "id": 1,
      "img": "image.png",
      "name": "name",
      "about": "about"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "img": "image.png",
      "name": "name",
      "about": "about"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "img": "image.png",
      "name": "name",
      "about": "about"
    }
  ],
  "programms4": [
    {
            "id": 1,
      "img": "image.png",
      "name": "name",
      "about": "about"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "img": "image.png",
      "name": "name",
      "about": "about"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "img": "image.png",
      "name": "name",
      "about": "about"
    }
  ],
  "programms5": [
    {
            "id": 1,
      "img": "image.png",
      "name": "name",
      "about": "about"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "img": "image.png",
      "name": "name",
      "about": "about"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "img": "image.png",
      "name": "name",
      "about": "about"
    }
  ],
  "programms6": [
    {
            "id": 1,
      "img": "image.png",
      "name": "name",
      "about": "about"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "img": "image.png",
      "name": "name",
      "about": "about"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "img": "image.png",
      "name": "name",
      "about": "about"
    }
  ],
  "programms7": [
    {
            "id": 1,
      "img": "image.png",
      "name": "name",
      "about": "about"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "img": "image.png",
      "name": "name",
      "about": "about"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "img": "image.png",
      "name": "name",
      "about": "about"
    }
  ]
}
```

Ionic template:

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-item *ngIf="let channel channel.programms7">    
    <ion-icon name="play" item-left large></ion-icon>
    <h2>{{channel.name}}</h2>
    <p>{{channel.about}}</p>
  </ion-item>
<ion-list
```

Please show me an example of how to print array in template.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the question here? You don't know how to read json file? how to loop it in template or?

Comment: yes! i cant read json ;(

Comment: You need to make a call to your file. See the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36749153/how-to-i-load-json-data-into-angular2-component

Comment: if you can, get array programms3 and show me an example!  thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate through an array in template using `ngFor` directive:

```
<div *ngFor="let j of myJson.programms3">
    {{j.id}}
    {{j.img}}
    {{j.name}}
    {{j.about}}
</div>
```

Here's [working Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/N8S7Hd6pCchzmKAmSUk1?p=preview).