# HTTP Interceptor in Angular 2

Tags: angular

I need in my angular 2 app a HTTP interceptor, which checks the HTTP status code of each response. If the status code is 401, I want to redirect the user to the login site.

Is there a simple way to implement this?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

You could implement a class that extends the `Http` one:

```
@Injectable()
export class CustomHttp extends Http {
  constructor(backend: ConnectionBackend, defaultOptions: RequestOptions) {
    super(backend, defaultOptions);
  }

  request(url: string | Request, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
    console.log('request...');
    return super.request(url, options).catch(res => {
      // do something
    });        
  }

  get(url: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
    console.log('get...');
    return super.get(url, options).catch(res => {
      // do something
    });
  }

  (...)
}
```

and register it as described below:

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [HTTP_PROVIDERS,
    new Provider(Http, {
      useFactory: (backend: XHRBackend, defaultOptions: RequestOptions) => new CustomHttp(backend, defaultOptions),
      deps: [XHRBackend, RequestOptions]
  })
]);
```

If 401 errors occur as this level, you could intercept them globally in the catch callback. You can leverage injected elements to handle them. For example, the `Router`.

Comment: Whith this approach I get always the following error: catch is not a function

I demonstrate this already: https://github.com/lexon0011/IssueDemonstrator

Could someone reproduce the error?

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34515173/angular-2-http-get-with-typescript-error-http-get-map-is-not-a-function-in/34515276#34515276 You need to import the catch operator like for the map one (replace map by catch in the answer ;-))