# Property 'catch' does not exist on type 'Observable<any>'

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

On the Angular 2 documentation page for using the Http service, there is an example.

```
getHeroes (): Observable<Stuff[]> {
  return this.http.get(this.url)
                  .map(this.extractData)
                  .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

I cloned the [angular2-webpack-starter](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter) project and added the above code myself.

I imported `Observable` using

```
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
```

I'm assuming the properties `Observable` are imported as well (`.map` works).  Looked at the changelog for rxjs.beta-6 and nothing is mentioned about `catch`.

Answer (score 252, accepted):

**Warning**: This solution is deprecated since Angular 5.5, please refer to Trent's answer below

=====================

Yes, you need to import the operator:

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
```

Or import `Observable` this way:

```
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';
```

But in this case, you import all operators.

See this question for more details:

- [Angular HTTP GET with TypeScript error http.get(...).map is not a function in [null]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34515173/angular-2-http-get-with-typescript-error-http-get-map-is-not-a-function-in/34515276#34515276)

Comment: Do you know why the properties aren't imported with `import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';`?  That seems more intuitive to me.

Comment: Because Rxjs is designed like this. The `rxjs/Observable` module doesn't import operators because there are a lot of operators. The `rxjs/Rx` module imports all... I think that it's a design choice.

Comment: importing from rxjs/Rx really slow page load down. compare request count with it v without = half the requests when u dont use rxjs/Rx but use for example rxjs/Observable

Comment: The rxjs/Rx import frequently won't even lint anymore, it's a blacklisted import. I know in the past this was seen as kind of ok (and I've done it), but nowadays it should never be part of a correct answer for anything other than playing around.

Answer (score 122):

With RxJS 5.5+, the `catch` operator is now deprecated. You should now use the `catchError` operator in conjunction with `pipe`.

> RxJS v5.5.2 is the default dependency version for Angular 5.

For each RxJS Operator you import, including `catchError` you should now import from 'rxjs/operators' and use the pipe operator.

#### Example of catching error for an Http request Observable

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
...

export class ExampleClass {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.http.request(method, url, options).pipe(
      catchError((err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        ...
      }
    )
  }
  ...
}
```

*Notice here that `catch` is replaced with `catchError` and the `pipe` operator is used to compose the operators in similar manner to what you're used to with dot-chaining.*

---

See the rxjs documentation on [pipable](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/pipeable-operators.md) (previously known as [lettable](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/lettable-operators.md)) operators for more info.

Comment: is `map(res => res)` required?

Comment: Nope, the RxJS `pipe` function lets you combine multiple functions into a single function. The pipe() function takes as its arguments the functions you want to combine, and returns a new function that, when executed, runs the composed functions in sequence. That mapping does nothing, since it is technically an identity function.

Answer (score 14):

In angular 8:

```
//for catch:
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';

//for throw:
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';

//and code should be written like this.

getEmployees(): Observable<IEmployee[]> {
    return this.http.get<IEmployee[]>(this.url).pipe(catchError(this.erroHandler));
  }

  erroHandler(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
    return throwError(error.message || 'server Error');
  }
```

Comment: I was trying something like this based on the previous version of Angular but couldn't pull it over correctly. Your answer helped me solve. This was exactly based on my model. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check the Angular version you are using and respective to that :

```js
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
```

or

```js
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';
```