# Angular 2 - Routing - CanActivate work with Observable

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-http

I have an **AuthGuard** (used for routing) that implements **CanActivate**.

```
canActivate() {
    return this.loginService.isLoggedIn();
}
```

My problem is, that the CanActivate-result depends on a http-get-result - the **LoginService** returns an **Observable**.

```
isLoggedIn():Observable<boolean> {
    return this.http.get(ApiResources.LOGON).map(response => response.ok);
}
```

How can i bring those together - make CanActivate depend on a backend state?

## # # # # # #

***EDIT: Please note, that this question is from 2016 - a very early stage of angular/router has been used.***

## # # # # # #

Comment: Have you read here? https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html search for Route Guards

Here is api reference for CanActivate: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/CanActivate-interface.html as you see it can return either boolean or Observable<boolean>

Comment: `canActivate()` can return an `Observable`, just make sure that the `Observable` has completed (ie. `observer.complete()`).

Comment: @PhilipBulley what if the observable emits more values and then completes? What does the guard do? What I have seen so far is use of `take(1)` Rx operator to achieve the completnes of stream, What if I forget to add it?

Answer (score 167, accepted):

You should upgrade  "@angular/router" to the latest . e.g."3.0.0-alpha.8"

**modify AuthGuard.ts**

```js
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
    constructor(private loginService: LoginService, private router: Router) {}

    canActivate(next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
        return this.loginService
            .isLoggedIn()
            .map((e) => {
                if (e) {
                    return true;
                }
            })
            .catch(() => {
                this.router.navigate(['/login']);
                return Observable.of(false);
            });
    }
}
```

If you have any questions, ask me！

Comment: It's worth pointing out that this works with promises in a very similar way. For my implementation, assuming `isLoggedIn()` is a `Promise`, you can do `isLoggedIn().then((e) => { if (e) { return true; } }).catch(() => { return false; });` Hopefully this helps future travelers!

Comment: I had to add `import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';`

Comment: not a good answer now IMO .. it provides no detail of what is happening server side ... it is out of date at alpha! ... it does not follow this best practice .. https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html#!#do-not-return-the-response-object .. see my updated answer below (hopefully one day above)

Comment: canActivate should retun Observable<boolean>

Comment: canActivate() also accepts return type of Observable<boolean> so we can directly return as observable<boolean>

Comment: Now it is `import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';`

Comment: Care to explain what you did?

Comment: I have 1 more XHR call after isLoggedIn() , and result of XHR is used in 2nd XHR call. How to have 2nd ajax call which will accept for 1st result? The example you gave is pretty easy, can you pls let me know how to use map if I have another ajax too.

Answer (score 91):

Updating Kery Hu's answer for Angular 5+ and RxJS 5.5 [where the `catch` operator is deprecated. You should now use the catchError operator in conjunction with pipe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47841788/1450420) and [lettable operators](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47198895/1450420).

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, Router, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { catchError, map} from 'rxjs/operators';
import { of } from 'rxjs/observable/of';

@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private loginService: LoginService, private router: Router) { }

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean>  {
    return this.loginService.isLoggedIn().pipe(
      map(e => {
        if (e) {
          return true;
        } else {
          ...
        }
      }),
      catchError((err) => {
        this.router.navigate(['/login']);
        return of(false);
      })
    );
  }   
  
}
```

Comment: I have 1 more XHR call after isLoggedIn() , and result of XHR is used in 2nd XHR call. How to have 2nd ajax call which will accept for 1st result? The example you gave is pretty easy, can you pls let me know how to use pipe() if I have another ajax too.

Comment: very useful also for angular 10

Answer (score 15):

[canActivate()](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/CanActivate-interface.html) accepts `Observable<boolean>` as returned value. The guard will wait for the Observable to resolve and look at the value. If 'true' it will pass the check, else ( any other data or thrown error ) will reject the route.

You can use the `.map` operator to transform the `Observable<Response>` to `Observable<boolean>` like so:

```
canActivate(){
    return this.http.login().map((res: Response)=>{
       if ( res.status === 200 ) return true;
       return false;
    });
}
```

Comment: what about a catch block? the catch block is called if its a 401 right?

Comment: In angular 4 doesn't work. It needs somewhere to define a generic type.

Comment: this is fantastic news

Answer (score 3):

I've done it in this way:

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {
return this.userService.auth(() => this.router.navigate(['/user/sign-in']));}
```

As you can see I'm sending a fallback function to userService.auth what to do if http call fails.

And in userService I have:

```
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';

auth(fallback): Observable<boolean> {
return this.http.get(environment.API_URL + '/user/profile', { withCredentials: true })
  .map(() => true).catch(() => {
    fallback();
    return Observable.of(false);
  });}
```

Comment: really good answer in terms of the .map() function - really really good :) - did not use the fallback callback - instead i subscribed to the auth Observable in the canActivate method - thanks very much for the idea

Answer (score 3):

This may help you

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Select } from '@ngxs/store';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map, take } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { AuthState } from 'src/app/shared/state';

export const ROLE_SUPER = 'ROLE_SUPER';

@Injectable()
export class AdminGuard implements CanActivate {

    @Select(AuthState.userRole)
    private userRoles$: Observable<string[]>;

    constructor(private router: Router) {}

    /**
     * @description Checks the user role and navigate based on it
     */

    canActivate(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.userRoles$.pipe(
        take(1),
        map(userRole => {
        console.log(userRole);
        if (!userRole) {
            return false;
        }
        if (userRole.indexOf(ROLE_SUPER) > -1) {
            return true;
        } else {
            this.router.navigate(['/login']);
        }
        return false;
        })
    );
    } // canActivate()
} // class
```

Answer (score -1):

CanActivate does work with Observable but fails when 2 calls are made like CanActivate:[Guard1, Guard2].
Here if you return an Observable of false from Guard1 then too it will check in Guard2 and allow access to route if Guard2 returns true.
In order to avoid that, Guard1 should return a boolean instead of Observable of boolean.

Answer (score -10):

in canActivate(), you can return a local boolean property (default to false in your case).

```
private _canActivate: boolean = false;
canActivate() {
  return this._canActivate;
}
```

And then in the result of the LoginService, you can modify the value of that property.

```
//...
this.loginService.login().subscribe(success => this._canActivate = true);
```

Comment: you're a genius, sir.