# Angular 4 - canActivate observable not invoked

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I am trying to implement [`canActivate`](https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate) in Angular 2/4 using RxJS observables. I have already read [another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37948068/angular-2-routing-canactivate-work-with-observable) on this. With the following code, my `canActivate` method works only once, when the app launches, but `hello` is never printed again when the `isLoggedIn` observable triggers new values.

```
canActivate(): Observable<boolean> {
  return this.authService.isLoggedIn().map(isLoggedIn => {
    console.log('hello');
    if (!isLoggedIn) {
      this.router.navigate(['/login']);
    }
    return isLoggedIn;
  }).first();
}
```

or this version is not working as well:

```
canActivate(): Observable<boolean> {
  return this.authService.isLoggedIn().map(isLoggedIn => {
    console.log('hello');
    if (isLoggedIn) {
      this.router.navigate(['/']);
    }
    return !isLoggedIn;
  });
}
```

However, it works fine with this code:

```
canActivate(): Observable<boolean> {
  return Observable.create(obs => {
    this.authService.isLoggedIn().map(isLoggedIn => {
      console.log('hello');
      if (isLoggedIn) {
        this.router.navigate(['/']);
      }
      return !isLoggedIn;
    }).subscribe(isLoggedIn => obs.next(isLoggedIn));
  });
}
```

What am I doing wrong in the first piece of code ?

EDIT: here is the `isLoggedIn` implementation

```
@LocalStorage(AuthService.JWT_TOKEN_KEY)
private readonly token: string;
private tokenStream: Subject<string>;

public isLoggedIn(): Observable<boolean> {
  if (!this.tokenStream) {
    this.tokenStream = new BehaviorSubject(this.token);
    this.storage.observe(AuthService.JWT_TOKEN_KEY)
      .subscribe(token => this.tokenStream.next(token));
  }
  return this.tokenStream.map(token => {
    return token != null
  });
}
```

that uses [`ngx-webstorage`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-webstorage). and RxJS [`BehaviorSubject`](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/subjects/behaviorsubject.md).

Answer (score 31, accepted):

### Challenges of AuthService with RxJs

This was one of the things I struggled with when switching from AngularJs's promises to Angular's Observable pattern. You see promises are pull notifications and observables are push notifications. As such, you have to rethink your AuthService so that it uses a push pattern. I kept thinking in terms of pulling even when I wrote working Observables. I couldn't stop thinking in terms of pulling.

With a promise pattern it was easier. When the AuthService was created it would either create a promise that resolved to "not logged in" or it would create an async promise that would "restore logged state". You could then have a method named `isLoggedIn()` that would return that promise. That allowed you to easily handle delays between showing user data and when you receive user data.

### AuthService as a Push service

Now, we switch to Observables and the *verb* **"is"** needs to be changed to **"when"**. Making this small change helps you re-think how things are going to work. So lets rename "isLoggedIn" to "whenLoggedIn()" which will be an Observable that emits data when a user authenticates.

```
class AuthService {
     private logIns: Subject = new Subject<UserData>();

     public setUser(user: UserData) {
          this.logIns.next(user);
     }

     public whenLoggedIn(): Observable<UserData> {
          return this.logIns;
     }
}

// example
AuthService.whenLoggedIn().subscribe(console.log);
AuthService.setUser(new UserData());
```

When a user passed to `setUser` it's emitted to subscribes that a new user has been authenticated.

### Problems With Above Approach

The above introduces several problems that need to be fixed.

- subscribing to `whenLoggedIn` will listen for new users forever. The pull stream is never completed.
- There is no concept of "current state". The previous `setUser` is lost after being pushed to subscribers.
- It only tells you when a user is authenticated. Not if there is no current user.

We can fix some of this by switching from `Subject` to `BehaviorSubject`.

```
class AuthService {
     private logIns: Subject = new BehaviorSubject<UserData>(null);

     public setUser(user: UserData) {
          this.logIns.next(user);
     }

     public whenLoggedIn(): Observable<UserData> {
          return this.logIns;
     }
}

// example
AuthService.whenLoggedIn().first().subscribe(console.log);
AuthService.setUser(new UserData());
```

This is much closer to what we want.

### Changes

- `BehaviorSubject` will always emit the last value for each **new** subscription.
- `whenLoggedIn().first()` was added to *subscribe* and *auto unsubscribe* after the first value is received. If we didn't use `BehaviorSubject` this would *block* until someone called `setUser` which might never happen.

### Problems With BehaviorSubject

`BehaviorSubject` doesn't work for AuthService and I'll demonstrate with this sample code here.

```
class AuthService {
     private logIns: Subject = new BehaviorSubject<UserData>(null);

     public constructor(userSessionToken:string, tokenService: TokenService) {
          if(userSessionToken) {
              tokenService.create(userSessionToken).subscribe((user:UserData) => {
                    this.logIns.next(user);
               });
         }
     }

     public setUser(user: UserData) {
          this.logIns.next(user);
     }

     public whenLoggedIn(): Observable<UserData> {
          return this.logIns;
     }
}
```

Here's how the problem would appear in your code.

```
// example
let auth = new AuthService("my_token", tokenService);
auth.whenLoggedIn().first().subscribe(console.log);
```

The above creates a new AuthService with a token to restore the user session, but when it runs the console just prints "null".

This happens because `BehaviorSubject` is created with an initial value of `null`, and the operation to restore the user session is going to happen later after the HTTP call is complete. AuthService will continue to emit `null` until the session is restored, but that's a problem when you want to use route activators.

### ReplaySubject Is Better

We want to remember the current user, but not emit anything until we know if there is a user or not. `ReplaySubject` is the answer to this problem.

Here's how you would use it.

```
class AuthService {
     private logIns: Subject<UserData> = new ReplaySubject(1);

     public constructor(userSessionToken:string, tokenService: TokenService) {
          if(userSessionToken) {
              tokenService.create(userSessionToken).subscribe((user:UserData) => {
                    this.logIns.next(user);
               }, ()=> {
                    this.logIns.next(null);
                    console.error('could not restore session');
               });
         } else {
             this.logIns.next(null);
         }
     }

     public setUser(user: UserData) {
          this.logIns.next(user);
     }

     public whenLoggedIn(): Observable<UserData> {
          return this.logIns;
     }
}

// example
let auth = new AuthService("my_token", tokenService);
auth.whenLoggedIn().first().subscribe(console.log);
```

The above will not *wait* until the first value is emitted by `whenLoggedIn`. It will get the `first` value and unsubscribe.

`ReplaySubject` works because it remembers the `1` items or emits nothing. It's the *nothing* part that is important. When we use AuthService in `canActivate` we want to *wait* until a user state is *known*.

### CanActivate Example

This now makes it a lot easier to write a user guard that redirects to a login screen or allows the route to change.

```
class UserGuard implements CanActivate {
      public constructor(private auth: AuthService, private router: Router) {
      }

      public canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {
           return this.auth.whenLoggedIn()
                      .first()
                      .do((user:UserData) => {
                          if(user === null) {
                              this.router.navigate('/login');
                          }
                      })
                      .map((user:UserData) => !!user);
      }
```

This will yield an Observable of true or false if there is a user session. It will also block router change until that state is known (i.e. are we fetching data from the server?).

It will also redirect the router to the login screen if there is no user data.

Comment: thanks you for the amazing comment you wrote ! I have one doubt about this pattern tough: I don't want subscribers to unsubscribe from the stream, because I want them to be aware of when a user logs out so they can react upon.

Comment: @user5365075 that's no problem. Notice that I use the `.first()` outside of the AuthService, and only in the `CanActivate`. That's because the activator needs only the current state. You can subscript to `whenLoggedIn()` and just don't unsubscribe. It will receive user data for log ins, and null for log outs.

Comment: It seems to me that the problem relies in when Angular calls `canActivate`. After a bit of console logging, it seems that Angular unsubscribes from the Observable once it has called it. That's the problem :) When the page is loaded, `canActivate` is being called => fine, user is not logged in, so display the login component. But when you login with success, `canActivate` is not called again, and since Angular has unsubscribe from it, the redirect does not happen.

Comment: Also, thank you for bringing the `ReplaceSubject` up, I didn't know about it and I think it's really useful for the case you mention !

Comment: @user5365075 Angular will not call canActivate again for child routes. So use the same activator on all routes that require a user session.

Comment: I'll mark your answer as my solution as it helped me understand why my code wasn't working.

Comment: Thank you @cgTag. This is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I made it

```
import { Injectable, Inject, Optional } from "@angular/core";
import { CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from "@angular/router";
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Rx";
import { AuthService, MyLogin, FacebookLogin, GoogleLogin } from "./auth.service";


@Injectable()

export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate  {

  constructor() {
  }

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | boolean {

    // return this.typeSelector(SigninComponent.loginTypeProperty);
    let isLogged: boolean = AuthService.loggedIn;
    window.alert('isLogged =' + isLogged);
    return isLogged;
  }
}
```

This is in another situation where I have to change the password:

```
import { Injectable, Inject, Optional } from "@angular/core";
import { CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from "@angular/router";
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Rx";
import { NewPasswordAuthService } from "./new-password.auth.service";
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { IPwCookie } from './IPwCookie.interface';


@Injectable()
export class NewPasswordGuard implements CanActivate  {


  constructor(private authService: NewPasswordAuthService, private router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute,)
  {

  }
  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | boolean {


    console.log('query params' + JSON.stringify(route.params));
    let hash:string = route.params.hash;
    let userId: number = route.params.userId;
    console.log('query params string' + JSON.stringify(route.params.hash));
    return  this.authService.activate(hash)
        .map(
          (): boolean => {
            console.log('check passed =' + NewPasswordAuthService.isAuthenticated());

            let passwordCookie:IPwCookie = {
              hash: hash,
              userId: userId
            };

            localStorage.setItem('password_hash', JSON.stringify(passwordCookie));
            return NewPasswordAuthService.isAuthenticated();
          },
          (error) => {console.log(error)}
        );
  }

}
```

As far as I see you should try adding a return type to the map function, this was one thing that gave me problems. If you do not add a return type to the map function, in this context it does not work.

So just do .map((): boolean => {} ...)

Answer (score -1):

```
canActivate(next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {
      return this.service.callServiceMethod())
        .map(result => {
          return true;
        }).catch(err => {
          return Observable.of(false);
        });

    return Observable.of(true);
  }
```