# Why ReplaySubject in AuthGuard doesn't work as expected when user signed in? Angular 10+

Tags: angular, authentication, rxjs, observable

I'm trying to implement authentication with Observables in **Angular 10**. I'm using ReplaySubject in the **AuthService** for set the current user signed in. The problem is that the **AuthGuard** never redirect to home after user sign in. I describe the issue below on `auth.guard.ts` file.

**app.routing.ts**

```js
const routes: Routes = [
      {
        path: 'not-found',
        component: NotFoundComponent,
      },
      {
        path: '',
        component: MainLayoutComponent,
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            canActivateChild: [AuthGuard],
            loadChildren: () =>
              import('./modules/landing/landing.module').then(
                (m) => m.LandingModule
              ),
          },
        ],
      },
      { path: '**', redirectTo: 'not-found', pathMatch: 'full' },
    ];
```

**auth.service.ts**

```js
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class AuthService {
  baseUrl = environment.apiUrl;
  private currentUserSource = new ReplaySubject<LoggedIn>(1);
  currentUser$ = this.currentUserSource.asObservable();

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  signIn(user: SignInDto) {
    return this.http.post(this.baseUrl + 'auth/signin', user).pipe(
      map((user: LoggedInDto) => {
        if (user) {
          localStorage.setItem('token', user.token);
          this.currentUserSource.next(user);

          return user;
        }
      })
    );
  }

  getCurrentUser(token: string) {
    if (token === null) {
      this.currentUserSource.next(null);
      return of(null);
    }
    const headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token);

    return this.http.get(this.baseUrl + 'auth/me', { headers }).pipe(
      map((user: LoggedIn) => {
        if (user) {
          localStorage.setItem('token', user.token);
          this.currentUserSource.next(user);
        }
      })
    );
  }
}
```

**app.component.ts**

```js
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private readonly authService: AuthService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getCurrentUser();
  }

  getCurrentUser() {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token');

    this.authService.getCurrentUser(token).subscribe(() => {
      console.log('user loaded');
    }, console.log);
  }
}
```

```js
export class SignInComponent implements OnInit {
  returnUrl: string;

  constructor(
    private readonly authService: AuthService,
    private readonly router: Router,
    private readonly activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.returnUrl = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.queryParams.returnUrl || '';
  }

  onSubmit() {
    this.authService.signIn({username: 'xxx', password: 'xxx'}).subscribe(
      (response) => {
        this.router.navigateByUrl(this.returnUrl);
      },
      console.log
    );
  }
}
```

**auth.guard.ts**

The problem is here... When user sign in the currentUser$ observable **is always null**,
everything else works fine (the token is saved in the local storage). If I try to refresh the page after sign in, the guard works fine but, if I signed in without update the page nothing happend.

```js
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivateChild {
  logged: boolean = false;
  constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router: Router) {}

  canActivateChild(next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.authService.currentUser$.pipe(
      map((auth) => {
        // when you sign in, auth object is always null
        // so the guard never redirect. But, if I refresh the page
        // after the token was saved the guard works fine, the auth object comes with data
        // What's the problem? :(
        if (auth) {
          return true;
        }

        this.router.navigate(['/signin'], {
          queryParams: { returnUrl: state.url },
        });
      })
    );
  }
}
```

So the question is, what Im doing wrong or ignoring?

Comment: Why are you using a ReplaySubject? This seems like you would want a BehaviorSubject.

Comment: @AdrianBrand According with this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44697159/angular-4-canactivate-observable-not-invoked), use ReplayObject is the best practice. Isn't it?

Comment: That answer is 3 years old. I didn't feel like reading that giant wall of text but my guess is that behavior subjects had not been added to RxJs back then. I might be completely wrong but for your requirement you should totally be using a behavior subject.