# RxJs pipe and lettable operator `map`: 'this' context of type 'void' is not assignable to method's 'this' of type 'Observable<{}>'

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs

I have this very basic example that uses lettable operator `map` with `pipe` from `rxjs@5.5`:

```
import { map } from 'rxjs/operator/map';

let o = of(1, 2, 3, 4).pipe(
    map((v) => v * 2)
);
```

But it produces the error `Error:(34, 5) TS2684:The 'this' context of type 'void' is not assignable to method's 'this' of type 'Observable<{}>'.` What's the problem here?

Answer (score 152, accepted):

Lettable instance operators should be imported from `rxjs/operators`:

```
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

As opposed to non-lettable equivalents which are imported from  `rxjs/operator`:

```
import { map } from 'rxjs/operator/map';
```

To learn more about lettable operator read:

- [RxJS: Understanding Lettable Operators](https://blog.angularindepth.com/rxjs-understanding-lettable-operators-fe74dda186d3)

Comment: for others who might google this: `first` is also a lettable operator

Comment: Thanks! This has got me stuck for many hours when trying out the [demo](https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/examples) components of angular materials. They are importing `map` from the non-lettable equivalents

Comment: @Bnrdo, yeah, I was confused as well. Good luck

Comment: Frustrating that VSCode seems to choose to automatically import from rxjs/operator/map.

Comment: @TomC, can't help you here

Comment: There are some bundling issues that may require you to do deep imports of pipeable operators in order to reduce your bundle size. In those cases, you will hit this if you accidentally import from `rxjs/operator/map` instead of `rxjs/operators/map`.

Comment: Thanks guys, its a tough one to spot

Comment: Thanks a lot! as @TomC mentioned, VSCode automatic import is frustrating 

Comment: @AngularInDepth.com Your answer will bloat the bundle size. Your answer should be changed to reflect Splaktar's comment.

Comment: Imports must have been clearly shown in all demos =/