# Return Observable inside the Promise

Tags: angular, typescript, promise, rxjs, observable

Could you tell me how can I return `Observable` here? I have tried many ways. But no success yet.

> [ts] A function whose declared type is neither 'void' nor 'any' must
>   return a value.

```
  deleteInvite(inviteId):Observable<HttpResponse<Object>> {
    this.getHttpHeader().then(headers => {
      return this.http.post(this.apiURL + "/deleteInvite", inviteId, { observe: "response", headers: headers })
    }).catch(err => {
      console.error(err);
    });
  }

  async getHttpHeader() {
    const accessToken = await this.getJWTToken();
    let headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization', `Bearer ${accessToken}`);
    return headers;
  }
```

Comment: `return this.getHttpHeader().then ...`

Comment: It says this: `[ts]
Type 'Promise<void | Observable<HttpResponse<Object>>>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<any>'.
  Property '_isScalar' is missing in type 'Promise<void | Observable<HttpResponse<Object>>>'.` @bugs

Comment: https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/creation/frompromise.html

Comment: @Sampath that's a different problem, see posted link

Comment: Any help how to use that with my use case? @DeblatonJean-Philippe

Comment: Any idea about how to use `fromPromise` with my use case? @bugs

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**FOR rxjs version: 6.0.0 onwards**

```
import { from } from 'rxjs';

 deleteInvite(inviteId):Observable<HttpResponse<Object>> {
    return from(this.getHttpHeader()).pipe(
        switchMap(headers => {
            return this.http.post(this.apiURL + "/deleteInvite", inviteId, { observe: "response", headers: headers })
        }),
        catchError(err => {
            console.error(err);
        })
    );
}
```

For older versions of rxjs:

Convert the `thisGetHeaders()` to an Observable by using `fromPromise`

```
import { fromPromise } from 'rxjs/observable/fromPromise';


deleteInvite(inviteId):Observable<HttpResponse<Object>> {
    return fromPromise(this.getHttpHeader()).pipe(
        switchMap(headers => {
            return this.http.post(this.apiURL + "/deleteInvite", inviteId, { observe: "response", headers: headers })
        }),
        catchError(err => {
            console.error(err);
        })
    );
}
```

Comment: It gives this error: `[ts] The 'this' context of type 'void' is not assignable to method's 'this' of type 'Observable<{}>'.`

Comment: could be related to your rxjs operators.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47198706/rxjs-pipe-and-lettable-operator-map-this-context-of-type-void-is-not-assi which is the version you are using?

Comment: `"rxjs": "5.5.2",` `import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { fromPromise } from 'rxjs/observable/fromPromise';
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operator/switchMap';` Any clue?

Comment: change to `import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators'`

Comment: Now, this error: `[ts]
Argument of type '{ observe: "response"; headers: void | HttpHeaders; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ headers?: HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; }; observe?: "body"; params?: Ht...'.
  Types of property 'headers' are incompatible.
    Type 'void | HttpHeaders' is not assignable to type 'HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; }'.
      Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; }'.`

Comment: check the return of `getHttpHeader()` .. the header parameter is showing incompatible type

Comment: Here it is: `(method) CommonProvider.getHttpHeader(): Promise<void | HttpHeaders>`

Comment: It seems `return this.http.post(this.apiURL + "/deleteInvite", inviteId, { observe: "response", headers: headers })` here `headers` is not being identified by the TS.  This thing here `switchMap(headers => {` Any clue?

Comment: if your function doesnt actually return void, you can force type like `<HttpHeaders>headers`

Comment: That is it. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Note: As of rxjs 6.0.0-beta.3, operators and observable creators should be imported from rxjs. Furthermore, fromPromise is not part of the public API anymore and its wrapped in the from method. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45784825/frompromise-does-not-exist-on-type-observable

Answer (score 0):

`getHttpHeader()` returns a `Promise`. Just wait for it to unwrap its value. Then return the result of `this.http.post` which is the expected `Observable`. For that, use the `await` keyword inside a `try/catch` block:

```
async deleteInvite(inviteId) {
    try {
        const headers = await this.getHttpHeader();
        return this.http.post(this.apiURL + "/deleteInvite", inviteId, { observe: "response", headers: headers });
    }
    catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
}
```

Then do `await deleteInvite(inviteId)` on the consumer side to handle the returned Promise.

Still, mixing Observable and Promise are complicated. Do all with Promises (or all Observables) can be easier : "`return await this.http.post().toPromise()`".

Comment: I need to return `Observable` form this method `deleteInvite()`. But with your implementation where it returns `Promise` due to `async`.

Comment: `this.http.post` will return an observable. You will have to convert this to a promise using `Observable.toPromise`

Comment: @Sampath: you're right. Using `async`/`await` is just a bit clearer. But we cannot unwrap the `Promise` returned by `deleteInvite` directly but another `await`: ` deleteInvite()` on the consumer side. The code is easier to read than with all the rxjs helper scaffolding.