# Chain promises then return observable

Tags: angular, promise, observable

This is quite confusing. I'm using angular(ionic) and calling two chain promises then would like to return as observable as below. I've tried adding return in front of two promises but of course throws compile error.

```
Type 'Promise<Observable<{ formInstanceId: any; questionId: any; repeatId: any; filename: any; isEquipment: any; }>>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<any>'.   Property '_isScalar' is missing in type 'Promise<Observable<{ formInstanceId: any; questionId: any; repeatId: any; filename: any; isEquipment: any; }>>'
```

I thought about use from(promise1) and from(promise2) but then it got even more confusing..

Main reason I want to change this to full observable because I want to use timeout() in the post() at the end of the code below

```
public uploadFile(formInstanceId, questionId, repeatId, filePath, isEquipment): Observable<any> {

    this._file.resolveLocalFilesystemUrl(filePath).then(result => {
    console.log("fileSelected", result);

    let fileName = result.name;
    let nativeURL = result.nativeURL;
    let path = nativeURL.substring(0, nativeURL.lastIndexOf("/"));

    this._file.readAsArrayBuffer(path, fileName).then(buffer => {
      let imgBlob = new Blob([buffer], {type: "image/jpeg"});

      let params = {fileName: 'attachment'};
      let query = this.encodeQueryData(params);

      let uploadFileURL = this._networkService.serverUrl + '/api/upload?' + query;


      return this._networkService.postFile(uploadFileURL, fileName, imgBlob).pipe(map(response => {
          console.log(response);
          return {
            formInstanceId: formInstanceId,
            questionId: questionId,
            repeatId: repeatId,
            filename: response[0].filepath,
            isEquipment: isEquipment
          };
        },
        error => {
          return throwError(error);
        }
      ));


    });
  })
```

}

Comment: What errors are you getting exactly?

Comment: @SmokeyDawson updated question

Comment: Is there a reason you want to return an Observable and not a promise??

Comment: @SmokeyDawson to use timeout in the network.postFile. rather than using .subscribe(), pipe(map) is not even reaching..

Answer (score 0):

You can use `from` operator from RxJs which will convert any Promise to Observable and chain it further (possibly using `flatMap`).
Refer: https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/creation/from.html

Similar questions answered here:

[Return Observable inside the Promise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50874091/return-observable-inside-the-promise)

[How to return Observable after some Promise get resolved in Ionic 2/Angular 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41585514/how-to-return-observable-after-some-promise-get-resolved-in-ionic-2-angular-2)
(`fromPromise` operator mentioned here should be replaced with the new `from` operator)

Another option is to use `async` `await` keywords in Typesript/ES6. Wherever you call `uploadFile` method, just use `(await uploadFile(formInstanceId, questionId, repeatId, filePath, isEquipment))` which will return an observable which was returned by `networkService.postFile()` method.

Your method will become:

```
 public async uploadFile(formInstanceId, questionId, repeatId, filePath, isEquipment): Promise<Observable<any>> {

    const result = await this._file.resolveLocalFilesystemUrl(filePath);
    console.log("fileSelected", result);

    let fileName = result.name;
    let nativeURL = result.nativeURL;
    let path = nativeURL.substring(0, nativeURL.lastIndexOf("/"));

    const buffer = await this._file.readAsArrayBuffer(path, fileName);
    let imgBlob = new Blob([buffer], {type: "image/jpeg"});

    let params = {fileName: 'attachment'};
    let query = this.encodeQueryData(params);

    let uploadFileURL = this._networkService.serverUrl + '/api/upload?' + query;

    return this._networkService.postFile(uploadFileURL, fileName, imgBlob).pipe(map(response => {
        console.log(response);
        return {
        formInstanceId: formInstanceId,
        questionId: questionId,
        repeatId: repeatId,
        filename: response[0].filepath,
        isEquipment: isEquipment
        };
    },
    error => {
        return throwError(error);
    }
    ));
}
```

Here is how you consume it:

```
(await uploadFile(formInstanceId, questionId, repeatId, filePath, isEquipment)).subscribe(result=> { /* ...Your code here... */ });
```

Async-await reference: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-1-7.html

Comment: thank you, in the method signature, return type is defined as promise. is that right?

Comment: Yes Promise of Observable of any. i.e. `Promise<Observable<any>>`