# Why concatMap does not work for multiple requests at once?

Tags: angular, typescript, xmlhttprequest, rxjs6

I have an array of objects data/ids received as parameter in the function where I should execute a post request for each element/id:

```
fillProfile(users) {

    const requests = [];
    console.log( 'USERS.length:', users.length );
    requests.push( this.http.post( '/test/add', users[i] ) );

    for ( let i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
        return this.http.post( '/test/add', users[i] ).pipe(
            map( (res) =>  {
                console.log( 'res: ', res );
                return res;
            }),
            catchError(err => {
                return throwError(err);
            })
        );
    }
```

It's working but it's not a good praxis and so fare I did search, it can be done via **forkJoin** or other operators. Have been trying these options/answers found in SO but unfortunately none of them did work.

One option I tried which doesn't work:

```
 ....
 return from(requests2).pipe(
     concatMap((request) => request.pipe(
         delay(500),
         map( res => {
             // console.log( 'res: ', res );
             return res;
         })
    ))
);
```

Any idea how to execute multiple requests and also get response and error of each one separately in a better approach?

Comment: I think we should add a mandatory field, in case some users think they are better and down vote a question, so that they are forced to enter the reason for down voting. The main target of the SO platform is help and sharing knowhow, not "just" clicking some buttons silently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed. It was my mistake cause thinking in the wrong direction and also had a bug when creating array. The way how it works now:

**in service:**

```
getArrayIds(users) {
    this.observables = [];
    for ( const i in users) {
        this.observables.push( this.http.post( '/test/add', users[i] ) );
    }
}


fillProfile(users): Observable<any> {
    return from(this.observables).pipe(
        concatMap((request) => request.pipe(
            delay(10),
            map( res => {
                return res;
            })
        ))
    );
}
```

**in *.component.ts:**

```
....
public results$: BehaviorSubject<Array<any>> = new BehaviorSubject([]);

....
this.surveyService.answerSurveyQuestions(body).subscribe(res => {
     console.log( 'response: ', res );
     this.results$.next(this.results$.getValue().concat(res));
});
```

Can even output the **results$** in the View ans debug all the response.
Thanks to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52483443/how-to-use-forkjoin-for-sequence-of-http-requests-angular-4) and the answers there!