# Returning value from BehaviorSubject in angular 6 guard

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, behaviorsubject

I'm going this direction because i've another guard who is validating the user on the token previously stored. This is what i was doing in previous version of rxjs, now in the latest you cant map on the subject.

```
canActivate(next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
           state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
  return this.authservice.behaviorsubject().map(x => {
    if (x) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  })
}
```

I need any guidence how to get this thing working. I've tried somting like this but wont return anything since never subscribed to it (and also its not a Observable its a AnonymusSubject when i console.log it)

```
canActivate(next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
           state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
  return this.authservice.behaviorsubject().pipe(
    map(x => {
      if (x) {
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    })
  )
}
```

Also tried converting it into observable with Observable.create() but wont work.
I know im missing something.
Heeeeelp :)

Comment: Hi it seems you don't subscribe to it to get your value back

Comment: @t3__rry you don't need to subscribe, look at the allowed return types. Or look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37948068/angular-2-routing-canactivate-work-with-observable

Answer (score 1):

return your behaviorSubject as an observable in your authservice:

```
private _authed: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject(null);

behaviorsubject():Observable<boolean> {
   return this._authed.asObservable()
}
```

Also a small comment: CanActivate works with observables, so if your behaviorsubject function returns a Observable with type boolean, you don't need to map it