# Why is undefined returned for an behaviorSubject which is actually defined in its class?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

In my angular web-application i have to get specific data but before i have to check if the user is logged in and i need to load some additional data. Lets say i want to get the orders of the logged in user, but to get the orders, i have to wait, until the group the user is part of is loaded, since i need it for loading the orders. (Very simplified my situation)

So i have created a pauser class so i can reuse it in my project:

```
import { BehaviorSubject } from "rxjs";

export class Pauser {
    private pauses: string[];
    pauser$: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);

    constructor(pauses: string[]) {
        this.pauses = pauses;
    }

    getPauser$() {
        return this.pauser$;
    }

    getLength() {
        return this.pauses.length;
    }

    removePause(pause: string) {
        const index = this.pauses.findIndex(p => { return p === pause });
        if (index != undefined){
            this.pauses.splice(index,1);
            this.pauser$.next(this.getLength() == 0);
        }
    }
}
```

Now my orders component looks like this:

```
private initPauser: Pauser = new Pauser(["group"]);

constructor(private authService: AuthService,
            private groupDataService: GroupDataService) {
    super();

    this.authService.getAuthenticated$().pipe(
        // Check if user is logged in
        switchMap(auth => {
            if (auth != null) {
                return this.initPauser.getPauser$();
            }
            else {
                return of(null);
            }
        }),
        takeUntil(this.destroyed$)
    ).pipe(
        takeUntil(this.destroyed$)
    ).subscribe(pauser => {
        if (pauser != null) {
            // Check if data already loaded
            if (pauser) {
                // Load the order Data
                this.onChange();
            } else {
                // Data not loaded -> Wait until the data is loaded
                // THIS FUNCTION RETURNS UNDEFINED ALTHOUGH IN DEBUGGER IT IS DEFINED
                this.initPauser.getPauser$().pipe(takeUntil(this.destroyed$))
                    .subscribe(res => {
                        if (res) {
                            // Load the order Data
                            this.onChange();
                        }
                    })
            }
        }
    });

    this.groupDataService.getActiveGroup$().pipe(takeUntil(this.destroyed$))
        .subscribe(group => {
            if (group != null) {
                this.activeGroup = group;
                if (this.initPauser.getLength() > 0) this.initPauser.removePause("group");
            }
        })
}
```

As described, after checking, if the data has already loaded (and is has not), i am trying to return the pauser$ behavior subject as observable, so i can subscribe to it. But the function return undefined.

What's even weirder is, when i hover over the first function call of `getPauser()$` while debugging, the debugger says it will return undefined, but it functions normaly and return the behavior subject as observable. Same with the second function call, but this time it really returns undefined.

[image]

Comment: If you solved your problem, it's best to add an answer below with the solution (not editing it into the question) and accepting your own answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

---

Like described in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50385913/returning-value-from-behaviorsubject-in-angular-6-guard) my problem was, not convertring the behaviorSubject into an observable. So i added the `as Observable<any>` part in my `getAuthenticated$()` function and now it is working!

```
  getAuthenticated$(): Observable<any> { 
    return this.afAuth.authState as Observable<any>; 
  }
```

Furthermore i changed up the code after some testing, if someone has the same problem

```
this.authService.getAuthenticated$().pipe(
      switchMap(auth => {
        if (auth != null) {
          this.auth = auth;
          return of(true);
        }
        else {
          return of(false);
        }
      }),
      takeUntil(this.destroyed$)
      ).pipe(
        takeUntil(this.destroyed$)
      ).subscribe(auth => {
        if (auth != null) {
          this.initPauser.getPauser$().pipe(takeUntil(this.destroyed$))
            .subscribe(res => {
              if (res){
                // Wait until data loaded, then execude Code
                this.onChange();
              }
            })
        }
      });
```