# Property 'catch' does not exist on type 'Observable<IEmployee[]>'.ts(2339) Error is not resolved by adding import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';

Tags: angular, typescript, service, rxjs, observable

When I hover over `.catch(this.errorHandler)`, I get a the error message

> Property 'catch' does not exist on type 'Observable'.ts(2339)

I can not import the catch function into angular typescript.

When I hover over `.catch(this.errorHandler)`, I get a the error message

> Property 'catch' does not exist on type 'Observable'.ts(2339)

According to another stack post:
[Property 'catch' does not exist on type 'Observable<any>'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37073705/property-catch-does-not-exist-on-type-observableany)
I should just add:

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch'
```

I also tried importing

```
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';
```

and

```
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

and using catchError instead of catch.

None of these worked

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
    import { IEmployee } from './employee';
    import { Observable, fromEventPattern } from 'rxjs';
    import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
    import {catchError} from "rxjs/operators"
    import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';

    @Injectable({
      providedIn: 'root'
    })
    export class EmployeeService {

      private _url : string = "../assets/data/employees.json";
      constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

      getEmployees(): Observable<IEmployee[]>{
        return this.http.get<IEmployee[]>(this._url)
                        .catch(this.errorHandler)
      }
      errorHandler(error:HttpErrorResponse){
          return Observable.throw(error.message ||"Server Error")
      }
    }
```

Comment: Don't, ever again, use imports of the form `import 'rxjs/add/...`. Those were for an obsolete version of RxJS. Use pipable operators, the one you need to use being called catchError (and being already imported). https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/pipeable-operators.md

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two issues:

1. Use `catchError` not `catch`
2. Use it with .pipe()

   ```
    return this.http.get<IEmployee[]>(this._url)
               .pipe(catchError(this.errorHandler));
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Try this (catchError with throwError):

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { IEmployee } from './employee';
import { Observable, fromEventPattern, throwError} from 'rxjs';
import {catchError} from "rxjs/operators"

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class EmployeeService {

  private _url : string = "../assets/data/employees.json";
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getEmployees(): Observable<IEmployee[]>{
    return this.http.get<IEmployee[]>(this._url)
                   .pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
  }

   handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {

     //throwError instead of Observable.throw
      return throwError(error.error.message ||"Server Error");
  };
}
```