# use variable this in another function

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic2

I Have a problem with the variable `this` in angularjs2 and ionic 2

I have this fuction:

```
getAnuncio(id_anuncio){
    console.log(id_anuncio)
    var token=this.local.get('token')._result; 
    var headers= new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    headers.append('Authorization', 'Token '+token);
    datos="id_anuncio="+id_anuncio;
    this.http.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/envios/getAnuncioPorId/',datos , {
        headers: headers

    })

    .subscribe(success => {
        this.anuncio=success.json();
        console.log("BIENNN");
        console.log(success);
        console.log(this.anuncio);
        return this.anuncio;



    }

}
```

I call it from another function:

```
cargarMapa(){

    this.anuncio=this.getAnuncio(this.envio.anuncio);
    console.log(this.anuncio);
    //console.log(anuncio);
    //this.getOferta(this.envio.oferta);
    //console.log(this.oferta)
}
```

But when I try to log `this.anuncio`, it is undefined.

I need to store the data in a variable to use it from other function.

Anybody could help me?

Here is the code: https://github.com/p02diada/cyclaClientv2/blob/master/app/pages/sending-details/sending-details.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could leverage the `do` operator this way for this:

```
getAnuncio(id_anuncio){
  console.log(id_anuncio)
  var token=this.local.get('token')._result; 
  var headers= new Headers();
  headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
  headers.append('Authorization', 'Token '+token);
  datos="id_anuncio="+id_anuncio;
  this.http.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/envios/getAnuncioPorId/',datos , {
    headers: headers

  })
  .map(res => success.json())
  .do(data => {
    this.anuncio = data;
  });
}
```

This way you can subscribe on the observable outside the `getAnuncio` method:

```
this.anuncio=this.getAnuncio(this.envio.anuncio).subscribe(
  (anuncio) => {
    // do something
    console.log(anuncio);
  }
);
```

Don't forget that things are asynchronous.

If you want to implement a kind of cache, use the following:

```
getAnuncio(id_anuncio){
  if (this.anuncio) {
    return Observable.of(this.anuncio);
  } else {
    var token=this.local.get('token')._result; 
    var headers= new Headers();
    (...)
  }
}
```

By using the `this.anuncio` directly is that you can't be sure that the data are there...

Comment: thank you for your answer but it does not work.

ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: TypeError: this.http.post(...).do is not a function

Comment: You're welcome! You need to include the `do` operator. See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34515173/angular-2-http-get-with-typescript-error-http-get-map-is-not-a-function-in/34515276#34515276. Replace `map` by `do` in it...

Comment: I have included the `do` operator now. It does not give me an error, But I can't use `this.anuncio` outside the function `getAnuncio` yet. I have tried it with a `setTimeout` because of the asynchrony and it does not work.

Comment: when I try `this.anuncio=this.getAnuncio(this.envio.anuncio).subscribe(
  (anuncio) => {
    // do something
    console.log(anuncio);
  }
);`

It give me an error: **ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined**

Comment: In fact `subscribe` returns a subscription not the result. You should this way:  `this.getAnuncio(this.envio.anuncio).subscribe( (anuncio) => { this.anuncio = anuncio; } ); `.

Comment: Regarding your error, I think that you forgot to return the observable related to the HTTP request: `return this.http.post(...`.