# What is the best way to load a JSON file in typescript?

Tags: jquery, json, typescript, angular

I want to load a local JSON file for testing purposes in my angular2 app written in typescript. I have 1) Included the jQuery.d.ts file, and tried to use $.getJson() 2) tried $.ajax() with async:false. The problem with both of these is that I cannot call functions outside of the callback function.

```
ngOnInit():any {
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajax({
            async: false,
            url: "../jsonfile/guestRecommendations/1.json",
            dataType: "json",
            method: "GET",
            success: function (data) {
                this.hello();
            }
        });
        alert(this.json_data);
    })
    this.json_data = "before";
}

 hello(){
    alert("hello");
}
```

}

This errror is thrown EXCEPTION: TypeError: this.hello is not a function. (In 'this.hello()', 'this.hello' is undefined)

I have also noticed that there is a function built into type script called ajaxGetJSON. But my IDE does not provides docs for how to use this function and I cannot find docs online for it. Any help with this question would be great.

Comment: You can use `$(document).ready(() => {` and `success: (data) => {`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is because you use a fat function instead of an arrow one:

```
success: (data) => {
  this.hello();
}
```

So the `this` keyword doesn't correspond to the component itself...

That being said, I would use the `Http` class of Angular2 to load a JSON file:

```
constructor(private http:Http) {
}

ngOnInit():any {
  this.http.get('../jsonfile/guestRecommendations/1.json')
          .map(res => res.json())
          .subscribe((data) => {
            this.hello();
            alert(data);
          });
}
```

Comment: I have tried your second suggestion and the typescript compiler throws an error Error:(28, 14) TS2339: Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Observable<Response>'. Do you know why this is?

Comment: You need to import the operator. This question could help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34515173/angular-2-http-get-with-typescript-error-http-get-map-is-not-a-function-in/34515276#34515276.

Comment: I've added import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'; and still get the error.

Comment: This solution along with another post solved my problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37618012/why-do-i-get-the-error-property-map-does-not-exist-on-type-observablerespon