# angular2 http request repeat many times

Tags: angular

today I use angular 2 to write a http request.I got the data in service,but I got `undefinded` in `component` .I don't know how to solve it,please give me some help.

service

```
export class AdminStoreService {
    data:Object;

    constructor(http:Http) {
        this.http = http;
    }

  findAll() {
    return this.http
        .get('/data/admin.json')
        .map((res:Response) => {
            console.log(data); //can get the json data
            this.data = res.json();
        });
}
```

}

console.log(data)

[image]

console.log(res)
[image]

component

```
export class AdminComponent {
admins:Object;

constructor(adminStore:AdminStoreService) {
    this._adminStore = adminStore;
    this._adminStore.findAll().subscribe(data => this.admins = data);
   console.log(this.admins);   // undefined
}
```

}

template   can't get the data

```
            <section *ngIf="admins">
                <tr *ngFor="let admin of admins" class="animated fadeInRight">
                    <td>{{admin.username}}</td>
                    <td class="alert">{{admin.authLevel}}</td>
                    <td>{{admin.operator}}</td>
                    <td>{{admin.created | dateFormat:'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'}}</td>
                    <td>{{admin.updated | dateFormat:'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'}}</td>
                </tr>
            </section>
```

Comment: Where or how do you call `getAdmins()`?

Comment: in template,I use *ngFor   <tr *ngFor="let admin of getAdmins()" class="animated fadeInRight">

Comment: source code is on github :https://github.com/nodejs-study/node-koa/tree/master/web/admin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time Angular invokes change detection, `getAdmin()` is called to check if it returns a different value as the last time.

There are different ways to work around this situation

- You can cache the data in the service and return it immediately when already available as explained in [What is the correct way to share the result of an Angular 2 Http network call in RxJs 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36271899/what-is-the-correct-way-to-share-the-result-of-an-angular-2-http-network-call-in)
- You can call `getAdmins()` in the constructor, assign it to a property and bind to that property instead.

```
export class AdminComponent {
    constructor(adminStore:AdminStoreService) {
        this._adminStore = adminStore;
        this._adminStore.findAll().subscribe(data => this.admins = data);
    }
}
```

The service also doesn't work the way it is built. It should be like

```
export class AdminStoreService {
  data:Object;

  /**
   * 构造函数
   */
  constructor(http:Http) {
    this.http = http;
  }

  findAll() {
    return this.http
        .get('/data/admin.json')
        .map(res:Response => res.json());
  }
}
```

**update**

Get debug output

```
  findAll() {
    return this.http
        .get('/data/admin.json')
        .map(res:Response => res.json())
        .map(data => { 
           console.log(data);
           return data;
        });
  }
```

Comment: I change the code as yours in service ,but has a error TypeError: this.http.get(...).map is not a function

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34515173/angular-2-http-get-with-typescript-error-http-get-map-is-not-a-function-in

Comment: `this.admins` is only set when `data => this.admins = data` is executed. This is why I modified your `findAll()` method. `data => this.admins = data` is a callback passed to `subscribe`. When the server eventually responds, this callback will be executed. You might want to add `<div *ngIf="admnis">...</div>` around your template or use `admins?.someProp` to avoid errors when `this.admins` is not yet set.

Comment: Can you please try to print `data` to the console like shown in my `update` in my answer. Can you also please edit your question and add there what you currently have. Code in comments is quite unreadable.

Comment: `console.log(this.admins);   // undefined
}` This is expected. This code is executed immediately. `data => this.admins = data` is executed much later, when the response from the server arrives. You need to move the code inside `subscribe(...)` to be executed when the data arrives. (like where you placed `console.log()` in `map(...)`

Comment: I know what you said,but my goal is show the data on template.

Comment: What does `console.log(data);` in `findAll()` print? How does the data look like?

Comment: source code is on github :[source code](https://github.com/nodejs-study/node-koa/tree/master/web/admin)  if you have time ,could you please download and try what wrong ?

Comment: If you could create a Plunker I would check it. I don't have TS environment setup up locally because I use only Dart myself.

Comment: this project I wrote with es6,not ts.