# Angular2 Http with RXJS Observable TypeError: this.http.get(...).map(...).catch is not a function

Tags: typescript, angular, rxjs

I have following Service which was working fine until today i got this error

> ```typescript
> TypeError: this.http.get(...).map(...).catch is not a function.
> ```

When I'm debugging this code it crashes when it comes to catch method.

```typescript
import { Test } from "./home.component";
import { Injectable }     from "@angular/core";
import { Inject } from "@angular/core";
import { Http , Response  } from "@angular/http";
import { Observable }     from "rxjs/Observable";

@Injectable()
export class HomeService {
   public constructor(@Inject(Http)  private http: Http) {}

   public getData (): Observable<Test []> {
        return this.http.get("./src/app/home/home-data.json")
            .map(this.extractData).catch(this.handleError);
    }

    public extractData(res: Response) {
        let body = res.json();
        return body.data || { };
    }

    public handleError (error: any) {
        // In a real world app, we might use a remote logging infrastructure
        // We"d also dig deeper into the error to get a better message
        let errMsg = (error.message) ? error.message :
            error.status ? `${error.status} - ${error.statusText}` : "Server error";
        console.error(errMsg); // log to console instead
        return Observable.throw(errMsg);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It seems that the catch operator isn't imported.

You could try to import it like this:

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch'
```

Or more generally this if you want to have more methods for observables:

```
import 'rxjs/Rx';
```

See this question:

- [Angular 2 HTTP GET with TypeScript error http.get(...).map is not a function in [null]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34515173/angular-2-http-get-with-typescript-error-http-get-map-is-not-a-function-in/34515276#34515276)

Comment: It worked! thanks. it's crazy that i have this `import 'rxjs/Rx` in my vendors file where i import my other dependencies also for angular2, but i believe i need to import this library to each file where i want to use this or in the main.ts.

Comment: @Thierry, apparently importing the entire rxjs/Rx is not good practice. Do you think it's not that much of an improvement to import only the operators that you need?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but in my case the problem was, I had import Required modules several times in Module.ts

Answer (score 0):

The '**O**' character in 'rxjs/**O**bservable' must be **Upper Case**.

Specifying it in lower case '**o**', will give you this and other spooky errors.
This must be imported like this:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';
```

It took me an hour to find it.
When using import, generally, the names are in lower case.
This is the first time I'm seeing this.
I hope it will help the others :)