# Can not find Custom HTTP Response headers in Angular 4.4.0-RC.0

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-http

I am trying to send some custom HTTP headers so that from client-end so that I can know the cause of the problem and show proper message to user. I am unable to get the response header from the below code (it shows null).

```
this.myService.getAllUsers().subscribe(results => {
    console.log(results)
},
error => {
    console.log(error.headers.get("ErrorCode"));            
});
```

But from the browser (chrome) I can see that I have the headers in the response.
    [Look at the image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lCZIv.png)

I was expecting the see the value "INVALID_SESSION" as the console output.

But getting null instead. Can anyone help?

Comment: What does your errorobject look like as json?

Answer (score 1):

Rather use `map` and `catch` from rxjs
See this: http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/viewarticle/error-handling-in-rxjs
or this: [Angular2 Http with RXJS Observable TypeError: this.http.get(...).map(...).catch is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38425825/angular2-http-with-rxjs-observable-typeerror-this-http-get-map-catch)