# How can resolve some stuff/ajax call before to display my view in Angular 2?

Tags: angular, observable, resolver

I've already tried this suggestion, but it doesn't work
Observable doest have any "fromPromise" method and typescript rises up an error.

```
import {Observable} from "rxjs/Rx";
import {Http} from "@angular/http";
import {GLOBAL_CONST} from "../global-const";
import {Resolve, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot} from "@angular/router";

export class ResolverSignupBegin{//} implements Resolve<any>{

    signupBeginData:any[];

    constructor(private http:Http){}

    getData(){
        return this.http.get(GLOBAL_CONST.apiPath + "/user/login/api-logged-in")
            .map(res => res.json())
            .subscribe(
                (data) => { console.log("data", data); return data; },
                (err) => { console.log("error", err); }
            );
    }


    resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot):Observable<any>{
        return this.getData();
    }


}
```

I havean error on "this".getData saying that " Error:(28, 16) TS2322: Type 'Subscription' is not assignable to type 'Observable'.
 Property '_isScalar' is missing in type 'Subscription'. "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you subscribe you get a `Subscription` but `resolve` needs to return an `Observable`.

Instead of subscribing yourself return an observable and let Angular do the subscription

```
getData(){
    return this.http.get(GLOBAL_CONST.apiPath + "/user/login/api-logged-in")
        .map(res => res.json())
        .catch((err) => { console.log("error", err); throw err;}
        .do(
            (data) => { console.log("data", data)},
        );
}
```

Don't forget that you need to import operators like `map` and `do`. See [Angular 2 HTTP GET with TypeScript error http.get(...).map is not a function in [null]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34515173/angular-2-http-get-with-typescript-error-http-get-map-is-not-a-function-in)