# Can't get `http.get` in angular2 to work

Tags: angular

I am trying to do a simple `GET` request with Http in Angular 2, following this [**TUTORIAL**](https://auth0.com/blog/angular-2-series-part-3-using-http/) and some other more up to date resources.

After successfully injecting the http component, I wrote the following code

```
 constructor(@Inject(Http) /* remove @Inject once @Injectable works */ public http:Http){
        http.get('https://api.travis-ci.org/config').toPromise().then((response => console.log(response.json().data) )
        //     .map(res => res.text())
        //     .subscribe(
        //     data => console.log(data),
        //     err => console.error(err),
        //     () => console.log('Random Quote Complete')
        // );
    }
```

As you can see there are a lot of comments as I have tried several combinations. I am getting these errors

> http.get(...).map is not a function(…)

if I try to use map

> Request header field X-XSRF-TOKEN is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

for anything else.. (toPromise) for example.

how can I make it work?

If I use `fetch`, the call works.. so it has to be something in angular.

Comment: You need to configure the server to allow CORS requests. The headers mentioned by the error message are expected by the browser, or it will refuse to make the request.

Comment: I am using travis api. it supports CORS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no method map() associated with 'Promise'.
Check the link [Angular 2 HTTP GET with TypeScript error http.get(...).map is not a function in [null]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34515173/angular-2-http-get-with-typescript-error-http-get-map-is-not-a-function-in)

I solved your issue. Here i used **Observer/subscriber** pattern. You just check the following code:

**rxjs-operators.ts**

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';
```

**travis-service.ts**

```
import { Injectable }     from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable }     from 'rxjs/Observable';
import './rxjs-operators';

@Injectable()
export class TravisService {
  constructor (private http: Http) {}

  getData (): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get('https://api.travis-ci.org/config')
                    .map(this.extractData)
                    .catch(this.handleError);
  }

  private extractData(res: Response) {
    let body = res.json();
    return body || {};
  }

  private handleError (error: any) {
    let errMsg = (error.message) ? error.message :
      error.status ? `${error.status} - ${error.statusText}` : 'Server   error';
    return Observable.throw(errMsg);
  }
}
```

And you can subscribe the data using the below code.

**travis.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, } from '@angular/core';
import { TravisService }        from './travis-service';

@Component({
  selector: 'travis-app',
  templateUrl: 'app/travis-app.component.html',
  providers: [TravisService]
})
export class TravisComponent implements OnInit {
    errorMessage: string;
    constructor(private travisService: TravisService) { }
    ngOnInit() {

        this.travisService.getData().subscribe(
            data => { 
                console.log(data);
            },
            error =>  this.errorMessage = <any>error
        );
    }

}
```

Comment: It was enough to add Observable. Thanks! Can you please add this specific line to the answer and mark the rest as TLDR? 
It is actually mentioned by angular's quickstart, but hard to notice due to all the clutter of information on their page. `import { Observable } from 'rxjs';` is in https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt6.html

Comment: I checked. `import { Observable } from 'rxjs';` not worked for me. But when i add `import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';` it works. Iam using rxjs-5.0.0-beta.12 version from npm.

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```ts
export class NoXSRFStrategy implements XSRFStrategy {
  configureRequest(req: Request) {}
}
```

```ts
@NgModel({
  providers: [{provide XSRFStrategy, useClass: NoXsrfStrategy}],
  ...
})
```

you shouldn't use this in production. 
Travis seems to miss `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` `"X-XSRF-TOKEN"`