# Angular2: canActivate

Tags: authentication, angular

Currently I want to implement canActivate function, everything I want is to send a request to server each time page requested and get true/false in a json response in order to understand is user authenticated and permitted to review current page.
And it seems that I completely stuck with observable and promise objects, which is new for me, what is what I have so far.

```
import { Injectable }     from '@angular/core';
import {CanActivate, Router}    from '@angular/router';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import {Observable, Observer, Subject} from "rxjs/Rx";

@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
    constructor(private router: Router, private http: Http) {}

    canActivate() {
        if (this.isAuthenticated()) {
            return true;
        } {
            this.router.navigate(['404']);
            return false;
        }
    }

    isAuthenticated() : Observable<boolean> {
        var subject = new Subject<boolean>();
        this.http.get("/index.php?module=Api&action=IsAuthenticated")
            .map((res : Response) => res.json())
            .subscribe(res => {
                console.log("next: returning true");
                subject.next(true);
            }, (res) => {
                console.log("next: returning false");
                subject.next(false);
            });
        return subject.asObservable().first();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution that works for me:

```
canActivate() {
    return this.http.get("/index.php?module=Api&action=IsAuthenticated")
        .toPromise()
        .then(this.extractData)
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A few changes

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
    constructor(private router: Router, private http: Http) {}

    canActivate() {
        return this.isAuthenticated().first(); // not sure if `.first() is still necessary
    }

    isAuthenticated() : Observable<boolean> {
        return this.http.get("/index.php?module=Api&action=IsAuthenticated")
            .map((res : Response) => res.json())
            .catch(err => return Observable.of(false))
            .map(res => {
                return true
            });
    }
}
```

If `isAuthenticated()` does some async execution, we don't get `true` or `false` back, we get an `Observable` that emits a `true` or `false` value eventually

What we do is to return the observable we get from `isAuthenticated()`

In `isAuthenticated with return the observable we get from`this.http.get()`and transform the emitted event. It seems the response from the server (`res.json()`) is not used. Therefore we use`catch()`to return`false`in case of an error and`true` otherwise.

Because the response from the server is not used `.map((res : Response) => res.json())` could be omitted, except this is where you expect an error from that should case `false` to be returned.
Also your production code might look different and require the response to be processed.

We don't subscribe anywhere, because this is what the router is doing when an `Observable` is returned from `canActivate` and if we call `subscribe()` we get a `Subscription` instead of an `Observable`.

Comment: Where I can take a `map`? Thank you

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the comment.

Comment: Well, it cause an error while compile because `map` method is unresolved, I suppose I should import `map` from elsewhere

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34515173/angular-2-http-get-with-typescript-error-http-get-map-is-not-a-function-in

Comment: console.log shows that `this.isAuthenticated` is always an object `{_isScalar: false, source: a, operator: a}` no metter what I'm sending from server

Answer (score 0):

`canActivate` can return either `Observable<boolean>`, `Promise<boolean>` or `boolean`.

As you are depending on asynchronous checking you cannot return a boolean.

It however looks like you could just simply do

```
canActivate(): Observable<boolean> {
  return this.isAuthenticated();
}
```

I'm no expert on `Observable` yet, but it would also be easy for you to chain on a call to redirect if you where not authorised.