# TypeError: this.http.get(...).map is not a function

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

In my Angular 4 app I'm trying to get some data from an API. I'm using [this](https://www.barbarianmeetscoding.com/blog/2016/04/02/getting-started-with-angular-2-step-by-step-6-consuming-real-data-with-http/) article which explains how to do that, but I'm getting an exception:

> TypeError: this.http.get(...).map is not a function

This is my code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { Person } from '../../../interfaces/Person';
import {configuration} from "../config";

@Injectable()
export class AdsService{
  private baseUrl: string = configuration.serverUrl;

  constructor(private http : Http){
  }

  getAll(): Observable<Person[]>{
    let people$ = this.http
      .get(`${this.baseUrl}/people`, {headers: this.getHeaders()})
      .map(mapPeople);

    return people$;
  }
}

function mapPeople(response:Response): Person[]{
  return response.json().results;
}
```

Any help will be profoundly appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 HTTP GET with TypeScript error http.get(...).map is not a function in \[null\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34515173/angular-2-http-get-with-typescript-error-http-get-map-is-not-a-function-in)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont see the map method imported.

Add this to your imports

`import rxjs/add/operator/map`

Answer (score 0):

You must import map in this file, for that you just need to add the following line:

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
```

OR

```
import 'rxjs/add/operators/map';
```

Also, if you are using Angular 5 or above, then the above imports have been sorted to :

```
import { map } from 'rxjs/operator';
```

OR

```
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

Add this and Enjoy !!! :-)