# Angular2 chaining functions during http request fails

Tags: angular, http, typescript

I would like to separate functions based on what they do

This is the scenario, when making http request i would like to separate the function that attaches the access token and header from the one that makes the http call

```
in my reset password.htmlform i have

<button (click)="tryresetPassword()">Reset password>
```

in the `reset-password.ts`

```
tryresetPassword(){
  ..fetch form data
 return this._authservice.resetPassword()
        .subscribe(
          ...here handle response
          )
 }
```

In the authservice

```
resetPassword(data):Observable<any>{
const body = JSON.stringify(data);  
return this.httpClient.post(this.authurl + '/default/resetpwd', body)
     .map(
       res=>{
          //set acess token
           return true
          }
        )

 }
```

now in the `_httpClient`

```
  post(url, data) {
   let headers = new Headers();
   this.createGeneralHeaders(headers);

   return this.http.post(url+this._accesstoken, data, {
     headers: headers
    });
```

After running the app am getting an error

```
  this._httpclient.post(...).map is not a function
```

NB the http in the httpclient is the angular2 http passed through the constructor

Wher am i going wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 HTTP GET with TypeScript error http.get(...).map is not a function in \[null\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34515173/angular-2-http-get-with-typescript-error-http-get-map-is-not-a-function-in)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try importing the map operator in your authservice

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
```