# Angular 4 this.http.get(...).map is not a function

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, angular-http

Hi i have problem with my code.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Car } from "./models/car";
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";
import { Http } from "@angular/http";
import 'rxjs'

@Injectable()
export class CarsService {
   private apiUrl = "http://localhost:3000/api/cars";
   constructor(private http : Http) { }

    getCars() : Observable<Car[]> {
        return this.http.get(this.apiUrl)
           .map((res) => res.json())
    }
}
```

With this code i have error:

> this.http.get(...).map is not a function

but when i add:

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'
```

Still have problem but error is:

> Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Can you help me? Thanks

Comment: what is the angular version

Comment: Angular CLI: 1.5.0
Node: 6.11.4
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 5.0.1

ou its 5.0.1 I thought I was using version 4

Comment: Angular 5 no longer includes `Http`. It has been superceded by `HttpClient`.

Comment: [angular-http-get-with-typescript-error-http-get-map-is-not-a-function-in-n](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34515173/angular-http-get-with-typescript-error-http-get-map-is-not-a-function-in-n)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned by others `Http` is deprecated, use `HttpClient` instead. `HttpClient` parses your response to an Object, so you remove the mapping of the response. Also, to avoid **[type checking errors](https://angular.io/guide/http#typechecking-the-response)**, tell Angular what kind of response you are expecting.

So import `HttpClientModule` and add it to imports array, after `BrowserModule`. In your Service import `HttpClient`, inject it in your constructor and use it the following way:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Car } from "./models/car";
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import 'rxjs'

@Injectable()
export class CarsService {
   private apiUrl = "http://localhost:3000/api/cars";
   constructor(private httpClient : HttpClient) { }

    getCars() : Observable<Car[]> {
      // tell Angular you are expecting an array of 'Car'
      return this.httpClient.get<Car[]>(this.apiUrl)
    }
}
```

Comment: Okey so i import my HttpClientModule and update my code.

 I run my server this http://localhost:3000/api/cars and it work. Everything is ok i see my Car[] 

But still in browser i have: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Maybe i Can ignore this or not? If everything is ok?

Comment: Well you are not mapping anywhere anymore? Have you tried restarting your project? Or are you using `map` somewhere else?

Comment: Wait like 5 min i add in answer my another code and tell you something.

Comment: I add answer can you check?

Comment: Everything is okay now. Thanks for help @AJT_82

Answer (score 2):

With angular5 **`HttpClient`** implementation already includes inner using of the map.so it works for you automatically.

just update it as

```
 getCars() : Observable<Car[]> {
     return this.http.get(this.apiUrl)
 }
```

Also make sure you are using  **`HttpClient`** instead of **`Http`**.

You can read more about this **[`here`](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/20460)**

Comment: So what i have to do?

Comment: @MarekPatyna check the link attached

Comment: did the answer help

Comment: Okey now i update my http and delete this: .map((res) => res.json())

Comment: And in my cmder i have this error : error TS2322: Type 'Observable<Object>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Car[]>'.

Comment: Yes  everything is okay now

Comment: did the answer help

Comment: Answer AJT_82 helped me.

Answer (score 0):

Edit your code

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Car } from "./models/car";
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";
import { Http } from "@angular/http";


@Injectable()
export class CarsService {
   private apiUrl = "http://localhost:3000/api/cars";
   constructor(private http : Http) { }

   getCars() : Observable<Car[]> {
     return this.http.get(this.apiUrl)
   }
}
```

since it automatically parse the response as JSON. You don't have to explicitly parse it.

Answer (score 0):

```
ngOnInit() {
 this.loadCars();

}

loadCars() : void {
 this.carsService.getCars().subscribe((cars) => {
  this.cars = cars;
  this.countTotalCost();
 })
}
```

So i move this `this.countTotalCost();`

from `ngOnInit` to `loadCars`

and now .map its ok.

I have only this error: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'undefined'. Current value: 'NaN'.

```
<div class="row" *ngIf="grossCost"> //this line error/error context
 <div class="col-sm-12">
  <div class="total-cost">
   <p class="text-right">TOTAL GROSS COST: {{ grossCost}} PLN</p>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```