# How to implement side effect on Observable retuned by HttpClient.get?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular5, observers

Does someone know how to use RxJS `do` operator on observer returned by angular's `HttpClient.get` method?

**Versions:**

- angular: 5.2.1
- rxjs: 5.5.6

With this version of angular I can't do this:

```js
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

...

constructor(
  private http: HttpClient,
) { }

...

this.http.get<Item>(url)
  .do(res => console.log(JSON.stringify(res)))
  .share();
```

Instead I have to add new steps with pipes. I can do it with `switchMap`, `map` or `share`, but I can't figure out how to do it with `do`.

I found out that I can do `import { _do } from 'rxjs/operator/do';`, but when I'm trying to use it like this:

```js
this.http.get<Item>(url)
  .pipe(_do(res => console.log(JSON.stringify(res)))
```

or like this:

```js
const observable = this.http.get<Item>(url);
observable.pipe(_do(observable, res => console.log(JSON.stringify(res)}));
```

I'm getting error:

```
[ts] The 'this' context of type 'void' is not assignable to method's 'this' of type 'Observable<{}>'.
```

Comment: `do` was replaced by [`tap`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/5.5.2/src/operators/tap.ts). Finding any real good docs on that seems to be a task. [This](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/a571bc14ea06d54f923af7295b7ad69de0e8d0f0/doc/pipeable-operators.md) could be useful.

Comment: @R.Richards thanks for the comment and for the links. Fortunately, I've solved the problem. But I'm curious, why there is this `do` functions then?

Comment: I have no doubt it is there for backward compatibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [pipeable operators](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/pipeable-operators.md) documentation explains, pipeable `do` was renamed to `tap`, alongside with several others. This was done in order to avoid collisions with reserved JavaScript keywords.

Pipeable operators are supposed to be imported as

```
import { tap } from 'rxjs/operators/tap';
```

Notice that pipeable operators are located in `rxjs/operators/...`, while `rxjs/operator/...` imports are used to patch `Observable.prototype`.

There are no concerns that would prevent `do` operator from being used some Angular versions. Both import styles are supported and valid, as long as a developer understands that there are certain differences between patch operators and pipeable operators that make the latter preferable in some cases. They are explained on [documentation page](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/pipeable-operators.md):

> 1. Any library that imports a patch operator will augment the Observable.prototype for all consumers of that library, creating blind
>      dependencies. If the library removes their usage, they unknowingly
>      break everyone else. With pipeables, you have to import the operators
>      you need into each file you use them in.
> 2. Operators patched directly onto the prototype are not "tree-shakeable" by tools like rollup or webpack. Pipeable operators
>      will be as they are just functions pulled in from modules directly.
> 3. Unused operators that are being imported in apps cannot be detected reliably by any sort of build tooling or lint rule. That
>      means that you might import scan, but stop using it, and it's still
>      being added to your output bundle. With pipeable operators, if you're
>      not using it, a lint rule can pick it up for you.
> 4. Functional composition is awesome. Building your own custom operators becomes much, much easier, and now they work and look just
>      like all other operators from rxjs. You don't need to extend
>      Observable or override lift anymore.

Comment: Pros of pipeables are explained in the docs. I've added them. It's a matter of taste. As long as you don't publish a library and understand the differences between them, old-fashioned operators are pretty much ok.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it with help of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34515276/2227895).

Actually, I had wrong import. This code works:

```js
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';

...

this.http.get<Item>(url)
  .do(res => console.log(JSON.stringify(res))
```