# Property 'do' does not exist on type 'Observable<IProduct[]>'

Tags: angular, rxjs6

After upgrading to Angular 6.0 and Rxjs to 6.0 I receive the following compilation error:

`Property 'do' does not exist on type 'Observable'.`

Here is the code:

```
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import { IProduct } from './product';

@Injectable()
export class ProductService { 
    constructor(
        private product: IProduct)
    {         
    }

    getProduct = () => { 
        return product.products
            // error on next line
            .do(data => console.log('All:' + JSON.stringify(data)))
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }

    private handleError(err: HttpErrorResponse) { 
        console.log(err.message);
        return Observable.throw(err.message);        
    }
}
```

Any idea?

Comment: Can you share a minimal code example which would illustrate the issue? That would go a long way toward helping us debug what is going on!

Comment: `import { tap } from "rxjs/operators";`
      
      try like this
              
          `return next.handle(clonedReq).pipe(tap((err: any) => {          }));`

Answer (score 108):

The problem is not with angular but with rxjs. rxjs introduced breaking changes from rxjs version 6.

To get your code working again without changing any of your code install the following package:

`npm install rxjs-compat@6 --save`

You should then be able to compile your project. `rxjs-compat` is meant to be a temporarily solution so you need to update your codebase to work with the new version.

---

### New Import Path

What you need to update:

1. Update import statements from

   `import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";`

   **to**

   `import { Observable } from "rxjs";`
2. Update your operator imports from

   `import 'rxjs/add/operator/do'`

   **to**

   `import { do } from "rxjs/operators";`

---

### Renamed Operators

Some operators have also been renamed due to name collisions with JavaScript reserved words. They are

1. `do` => `tap`
2. `catch` => `catchError`
3. `switch` => `switchAll`
4. `finally` => `finalize`

---

### No Operator Chaining

You also then can't chain your operators anymore you need to use the `pipe` operator e.g.

```js
// an operator chain
source
  .map(x => x + x)
  .mergeMap(n => of(n + 1, n + 2)
    .filter(x => x % 1 == 0)
    .scan((acc, x) => acc + x, 0)
  )
  .catch(err => of('error found'))
  .subscribe(printResult);
```

```js
// must be updated to a pipe flow
source.pipe(
  map(x => x + x),
  mergeMap(n => of(n + 1, n + 2).pipe(
    filter(x => x % 1 == 0),
    scan((acc, x) => acc + x, 0),
  )),
  catchError(err => of('error found')),
).subscribe(printResult);
```

Comment: +1 for detailing renamed operators. I had picked up the namespace and pipe changes but missed the name changes.

Comment: update: `import {tap} from 'rxjs/internal/operators';`

Comment: what about 'share' operator? was it renamed/changed/removed?

Comment: @Mario It does not seem to be renamed https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/multicasting/share.html

Comment: @TjaartvanderWalt as far as naming goes no, but i believe that it is no longer a property of the 'Observable' class. Instead it should be called as a method within the first inline method of pipe method. Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50885262/replacing-the-share-function-for-in-rxjs6

Comment: and so `.do()` becomes `.pipe(tap())`

Comment: 'npm install rxjs-compat@6 --save' solved this error for me and was needed for Angular CLI 7.2.1 (rxjs 6.3.3) as well.

Answer (score 20):

I appreciate Tjaart van der Walt's response about how to resolve the "breaking changes" introduced in Angular/rxjs7++.  But I still encountered several problems trying to apply his response to my Angular interceptor:

Here is the updated code (the sections that failed to compile are marked "OLD")

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor, HttpResponse} from '@angular/common/http';
import {HttpHandler, HttpRequest, HttpErrorResponse} from '@angular/common/http';

/*
  OLD:
  import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
  import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';
 */
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { of } from 'rxjs';
import { tap, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { AuthService } from './auth.service';

@Injectable()
export class StockAppInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(private authService: AuthService) {}

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    if (this.authService.authToken) {
      const authReq = req.clone({
        headers: req.headers.set(
          'Authorization',
          this.authService.authToken
        )
      });
      console.log('Making an authorized request');
      req = authReq;
    }
    /*
     * OLD:
     * return next.handle(req)
     *   .do(event => this.handleResponse(req, event),
     *      error => this.handleError(req, error));
     */
    return next.handle(req).pipe(
      tap(
        event => this.handleResponse(req, event),
        error => this.handleError(req, error)
      )
    );
  }


  handleResponse(req: HttpRequest<any>, event) {
    console.log('Handling response for ', req.url, event);
    if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
      console.log('Request for ', req.url,
          ' Response Status ', event.status,
          ' With body ', event.body);
    }
  }

  handleError(req: HttpRequest<any>, event) {
    console.error('Request for ', req.url,
          ' Response Status ', event.status,
          ' With error ', event.error);
  }
}
```

Required changes include changing `import` paths, and substituting `pipe()`, `tap()` and `of()`.

This link is also a good resource for RxJS6 changes:

https://www.academind.com/learn/javascript/rxjs-6-what-changed/

Comment: I was creating an interceptor, and this answer helped me a lot. Thank You.

Answer (score 15):

Rxjs 6 has introduced some breaking changes and the "do" operator has been replaced by the "tap" operator (from '`rxjs/internal/operators`').

You could refactor your code using the new operator or still use the old 'do' syntax by adding the rxjs-compat library for backward compatibility (`npm install --save rxjs-compat`).

Note that before RxJs 6 you had to import the 'do' operator :

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';
```

More details here : [Angular HTTP GET with TypeScript error http.get(...).map is not a function in [null]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34515173/angular-http-get-with-typescript-error-http-get-map-is-not-a-function-in-n/34515276#34515276)

Comment: it is already imported, please refer my code snapshot attached with the problem!

Comment: As cited above, this is *NOT* correct for rxjs 6.0 or higher.  You need to import `tap` from `rxjs/operators` and change your syntax.  Or import `rxjs-compat@6` (a "last resort", if you can't avoid updating your code).

Answer (score 6):

> "do" operator had replaced with "tap" operator in rxjs 6 , that why
> this error occurs "Property 'do' does not exist on type
> 'Observable<IProduct[]>'"
>
> To Fix this Error, you have two options
>
> Solution 1:   Patch your code ... it will work fine with do operator

```
npm install rxjs-compat@6 --save
```

> Solution 2: Replace your **next.handle** code with below code

```
 return next.handle(req).pipe(
      tap(
        event => this.handleResponse(req, event),
        error => this.handleError(req, error)
      )
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use in your typescript file:

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';
```

as simple as that.
Thanks.