# Replacing the share() function for in rxjs6

Tags: angular

I'm trying to have the details of the logged in user available to my application.  I have the following code which worked in Angular 5, but doesn't work in Angular 6 because the .share() function is missing in rxjs 6

Do I need the .share() function?  Does my code look ok with regards to the changes for rxjs 6?

```
export class UserService {

    readonly baseUrl = `${environment.apiUrl}/auth`;

    private loggedIn = false;

    private currentUserSubject = new BehaviorSubject<LoggedInUser>({} as LoggedInUser);
    currentUser = this.currentUserSubject.asObservable().share();


    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    login(userLogin: UserLogin) {
        return this.http.post<any>(this.baseUrl + '/login', { username: userLogin.email, password: userLogin.password })
            .subscribe(result => {
                localStorage.setItem('auth_token', result.auth_token);
                this.setCurrentUser();
                return true;
            });
    }

    setCurrentUser(): void {
        if (localStorage.getItem("auth_token")) {
            let jwtData = localStorage.getItem("auth_token").split('.')[1]
            let decodedJwtJsonData = window.atob(jwtData)
            let decodedJwtData = JSON.parse(decodedJwtJsonData)
            this.currentUserSubject.next(
                {
                    firstName: decodedJwtData.given_name,
                    id: decodedJwtData.id,

                }
            );
        }
    }

    getCurrentUser(): LoggedInUser {
        if (this.currentUserSubject.value.id) {
            return this.currentUserSubject.value;
        }
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.currentUserSubject.unsubscribe();
    }

    isLoggedIn() {
        this.setCurrentUser();
        if (this.currentUserSubject.value.id) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: share does exist in RxJS6. It's an operator, and as for every other RxJS operator, the syntax changed to be a *pipeable* operator. https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/pipeable-operators.md, https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/v6/migration

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`RxJS v5.5.2+` has moved to `Pipeable` operators to improve tree shaking and make it easier to create custom operators.
 now `operators` need to be  combined using the `pipe` method
**[Refer This](https://blog.angularindepth.com/rxjs-understanding-lettable-operators-fe74dda186d3)**
**New Import**

```
import { share} from 'rxjs/operators';
```

**Modified Code**

```
   currentUser = this.currentUserSubject.asObservable().pipe(share());
```

[`RxJS 6 - What Changed? What's New?`](https://www.academind.com/learn/javascript/rxjs-6-what-changed/)

> Do I need the .share() function?

Depends on your use case, if you aren't using multiple async `pipe`  you don't require `share` operator 
`Subject`  acts as a bridge/proxy between the source `Observable` and many `observers`, making it possible for multiple `observers` to share the same `Observable` execution.

*Async pipe does not use share or have any optimizations for multiple repeats uses in a template. It creates a subscription for each use of the Async pipe in a template.*

***Refer***:
[`RxJS: Understanding the publish and share Operators`](https://blog.angularindepth.com/rxjs-understanding-the-publish-and-share-operators-16ea2f446635)