# Detect missing augmentation imports in an Angular app

Tags: angular, typescript

When running my angular application after compiling it with --prod, I often get some `XXX is not a function` errors.

They are usually caused by some missing augmentations on Observable (I am using RxJS 5). They are fixed by adding the correct `import 'rxjs/add/operator/XXXX';` in the correct file, after finding this 'correct file' which can be long. And then are I have to rebuild the application, re-test and fix the next similar error.

(see [Angular HTTP GET with TypeScript error http.get(...).map is not a function in [null]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34515173/angular-http-get-with-typescript-error-http-get-map-is-not-a-function-in-n) for similar problems)

My question : is there a way to detect all the missing augmentation imports ?

Eventually using Webstorm, angular-cli, a good combination of find/grep/awk or any other tool.

Comment: Use pipeable operators. That's one of the main reasons they have replaced the old operators (which don't exist anymore in RXJS6, and thus Angular 6). The Angular 6 update procedure will do that automatically for you.

Comment: I know it is the way to go, but we would prefer to postpone a few month this upgrade to RxJs6/Angular6. And it will solve 99% of these missing augmentations import problems