# IntelliJ using TypeScript 5.0.3 to compile Vue project instead of Vue TypeScript

Tags: typescript, vue.js, intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

I am running IntelliJ IDEA 2023.1 (Ultimate Edition) Build #IU-231.8109.175, built on March 28, 2023. I cannot get my project to compile with "Vue TypeScript". This causes some types mismatches to be ignored.

Under Languages & Frameworks > JavaScript > Code Quality Tools > ESLint I have the following configuration:  {**/*,*}.{vue,js,ts,jsx,tsx,html}

How could I force IntelliJ to run the Vue TypeScript compiler?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31604486/can-i-update-the-typescript-version-in-webstorm

Comment: It's unclear what's "Vue TypeScript", it's safe to assume that it's TS version that's installed in Vue project

Comment: Please could you clarify what you mean by compiling your project with Vue TypeScript compiler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In IDEA 2023.1, Typescript language service is turned off for `.vue` files if the Typescript version is 5.x because the Vue language service is not compatible with `typescript@5` that introduced some breaking changes, please see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-60063/IDE-shows-incorrect-errors-for-import-statements-with-Typescript-5.0-in-Vue-SFC#focus=Comments-27-7057634.0-0

As a workaround, you can try changing the typescript version to `Bundled`  in **Settings | Languages & Frameworks | TypeScript**